# How to configure Glassfish to drop hanging requests?

Tags: glassfish, threadpool, glassfish-3

Can I configure Glassfish to drop any request that takes longer than 10 seconds to process?

Example:
I'm using Glassfish to host my web service. The thread pool is configured to have max 5 connections.

My service has a method that does this:

```
System.out.println("New request");
Thread.sleep(1000*1000);
```

I'm creating 5 requests to the service and I see 5 messages "New request" in the log. Then the server stop to respond for a looong time.

In live environment all requests must be processed in less than a second. If it takes more time to process then there is a problem with the request and I want Glassfish to drop such requests but stay alive and serve other requests.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using a workaround in the code. At the beginning of my web method I launch a separate thread for request processing with a timeout as it was suggested here: [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

I do not like this solution and still believe that there must be a configuration setting in the Glassfish to apply this logic to all requests, not to just one method.