# Limit time on a functioncall

Tags: java, multithreading, time, depth-first-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

I am using a function call to make a recursive search in a tree. It sets the best answer in a class variable and the function itself doesn't return anything.

So I want to limit the allowed time for the function. If the time has run out it simply stops and the thread is destroyed. How should I do if I want to limit the call to two seconds:

```
runFunction(search(),2000);
```

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 5 or greater, I would use the ExecutorService interface and the submit method:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    search();
    }
});
try {
    future.get(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // handle time expired
}
```

Using this method, you can also adjust your thread to return a value by submitting a Callable instead of a Runnable.

Comment: That would only work if `search` is interruptible.

Comment: Perfect! Do I need to destroy the thread or is it done automaticly?