# Is there a way to specify the duration for which a task should run using Quartz library

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, timing, executorservice

I am looking for a way to specify the duration for a particular task to run - e.g. a particular file cleaner task may not run longer than 2 minutes. If it finishes under 2 minutes - great, but it should terminate after 2 minutes.

Does Quartz or any other library provide some effective way of doing so?

Comment: By what means you expect the thread being terminated?  The preferred way to end a thread is to end it peacefully by your program logic.  e.g. a flag indicating we should jump out from loop, etc.  Therefore it is almost impossible for anyone but yourself to "terminate" your thread.  Have another thread, wait 2 min, and do the termination work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in quartz. You'll have to encapsulate the "timeout manager" in your job implementation.

You should detach the actual job implementation in a separate Task that is managed by the Quartz Job.

Take a look to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275596/1517816

Assume your QuartzJob is the Test class and move your business logic in the Task class.

Hope it helps