# Can we kill a Job using Customized Quartz Thread Pool Implementation?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I would like to kill the Quartz Thread and there is no direct way to achieve this in Quartz.

can we create our own Customized Quartz Thread Pool Implementation to achieve the same by adding the required details to identify the thread and kill the same by java thread.interrupt.

Could someone share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you seen [`InterruptableJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html)?

Comment: It will just returns the boolean and not actually terminates the job.

Comment: Take a look to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081385/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-current-running-quartz-job/13082674#13082674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done using socket programming and able to open a socket and trace the socket and finally kill the socket. This has been achieved in a different way.

Assume, a Job is connected with a third party server and third party server doesn't sends the response in a given time.