# Destroying a thread, having a never ending function int its run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

In my `run()` method of my Thread class, I am calling a never ending function.
I need the thread to run only for a specific duration.

Am not able to control the thread once its started, Is their any way to destroy it?

I have tried `yield()`, `sleep()`, etc...

PS - I cannot change the never ending function

Comment: did u try interrupting it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop() ? stop() is deprecated though, it's better to edit the function so it can be stopped by changing a variable, that way it stops at a safe point every time

Comment: yes, i have tried still no success

Comment: A thread is never stopped unless itself is willing to

Comment: Can you define the duration and how it running for ever, do you have a loop like `while(true) {}`

Comment: as mentioned, I cannot change the never ending function. It is used by other process too, If changed it will mess the project.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread
 
see the answer from @BalusC

Answer (score 2):

From oracle Java Docs:

```
public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        heavyCrunch(inputs[i]);
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
             // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
             return;
        }
    }
}
```

Your thread should check interrupted condition after each loop to see if it was interrupted. If you are calling a method that just does `while(true){}` then I am afraid there is no way interrupting it and `stop()` MUST never be called on a thread.

***It is the programmers responsibility to make a long running method responsive to interrupts.***

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html answers all your questions.. particularly section What should I use instead of Thread.stop?

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer should also contain some explanation. This looks like only link answer which are not suitable.

Comment: Ok.. thanks Narendra, will try to give more detailed answers going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be too much, but this is how I would solve it, if you do not want to mess with Interrupt.

```
 public class ThreadTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
          ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
      test.go();
}

void go() throws InterruptedException{
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(new LongRunnable());
    if(!service.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
        System.out.println("Not finished within interval");
        service.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

}

```
 class LongRunnable implements Runnable {
      public void run(){
    try{
        //Simultate some work
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

Basically you are wrapping your runnable in a ExecutorServie and if it's not finished within the interval, you basically kill it - send the interruption to it.