# Java Pausing Process and Executing with another flow

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to do this thing, but not getting how? The code requests that Network Service  send SMS Billing information; the Network Service's Responses are recorded when billing is succeeds or fails. 
        Sometimes it takes long time to get the Response and I want to cancel/pause that process and re-send the request with new number.

```
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
String resp = new SmsConnection().doResponseRequest(sms);
long totalResponseTime=((System.currentTimeMillis() - before )/1000);
```

I can only record `totalResponseTime` and sometime it takes 50-100 seconds to get the response from Service. Is there any way where I can say

"If `resp` is taking more than 15 seconds cancel/pause this Request and re-send another at the same time. After we receive the response we will process that request."

I need something like a TimeOut Option for receiving the response. Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: are you restricted to threads? why not use them they are flexible and easy to control!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), by extracting `new SmsConnection().doResponseRequest(sms);` into [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread).

Comment: ..Thanks.  This application is already in ExecutorService. I just want to cancel this part if it takes too much time to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Callable:

```
Future<String> futureResponse = service.submit(new YourCallable); //service is the ExecutorService that you use
//this will block for 15 seconds here
String result = futureResponse.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //this needs to wrapped in a try catch with TimeoutException
if(result == null){
    //You did not get the result in 15 seconds
    futureResponse.cancel(true);//kill this task

    //schedule a new task
    service.submit(new YouCallable());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution for my problem! Thanks Eugene and Dmitry for supplying Hint and Suggestion! I created a method for receiving response and then called this method inside  synchronized(this) {} block!!

```
 public String getResponse(final StsSmsSubmit sms) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        String response="";
       Callable<String> responsecode=new Callable<String>() {


        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {

           final String resp = new StsSmsConnection().doRequest(sms);
           return resp;
        }
    };
       ExecutorService service=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
         Future task=service.submit(responsecode);
         try{
         response=(String) task.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch(TimeoutException tE)
    {
       System.out.println("TimeOutException Occurred  "+tE.getMessage()+"at "+ new Date());
       log.fatal("TimeOut Exception is catched. at "+ new Date());
       response="TimeOut";
    }
         service.shutdown();


       return response;

    }
```