# Http Request PUT and GET timeout

Tags: java, android, http

According to the Apache documentation, the 2 timeouts used on their sockets are the following:

CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT='http.socket.timeout': defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets). A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. This parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Integer. If this parameter is not set, read operations will not time out (infinite timeout).

CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT='http.connection.timeout': determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. This parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Integer. If this parameter is not set, connect operations will not time out (infinite timeout).

Suppose I set both to 5s.
If I perform an HTTP GET request on a slow server, and the following happens:
The connnection is done within 5s. (CONNECTION_TIMEOUT is not triggered)
IP packets keep trickling say every 4s (SO_TIMEOUT is not triggered)
However it could take minutes for my HTTP GET or PUT to effectively complete.
Is there a way to set a timeout to my overall GET or PUT request so that I can notify the user and/or give up.

Comment: You can set timeout in the instance of the `HttpGet` class and it will work only for 1 request.

Comment: I have not found an obvious way to do this. Could you please describe it a bit more.

Comment: Here is an example that you can use these parameters for either DefaultHttpClient or GetMethod: http://stackoverflow.com/a/694009/427225.

Comment: I understand how to set The Socket and connection timeout, but they don't work for my use case. If I have  timeouts of 5s and IP packets come every 4 seconds, the request could take minutes to complete without any timeout at the HTTP level. I want to be able to notify the user that his connection is slow or just abort the request if not completed in a certain timeFrame.

Comment: I would just display a progress bar, users know themselves what connection speed they have. As to 'abort the request if not completed in a certain timeFrame' you can look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275596/427225.