# Make thread go to finally after certain time has passed

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread which may get stuck and keep running forever. Thus after a certain amount of time, I would like it to stop executing, go to the finally method to do cleanup, and then die. How would I go about doing this safely? Thanks.

My first thought on how to do this was to make a child thread and have that sleep and then do the cleanup. But then when the parent thread is still trying to run and it can't so it outputs an error.

Comment: Is there a top level loop in this thread?  Is there a piece of code that is reached repeatedly even if the thread gets stuck?  Can you predict how many times the thread would loop/recurse before it starts working?

Comment: Ideally, you should have some flag which your thread checks periodically.  If the flag is set, your thread should conduct an orderly shutdown of it's task.

Comment: There is no loop or anything. The thread sends data but if it taking too long to send data I want it to shut down. How can I have it check periodically if it is stuck on one line of code?

Comment: You set timeouts. The only tasks that block like that typically have a way to set timeouts. If there isn't a way to set a timeout, you need to create a way by abstracting the blocking call.

Comment: It would be easier if you could tell us what the "one line of code" does. And do you mean finally or [finalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29)?

Comment: You need to make your code cooperate. If you find yourself having to write some other piece of code to *make* some existing piece of code do the right thing, that should be a sign that that other piece of code needs to be fixed directly.

Comment: How does it send data?  What does it call?  If you tell us what it's blocked on, we may be able to suggest a way of unblocking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your code into a Callable and use an ExecutorService to get a Future.  Then use get with a timeout, which throws a TimeoutException if not done by then.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275596/53897 for a full example.

Comment: I completely forgot about future. +1

Comment: This doesn't cause the active thread to die. Only the waiting thread that invoked the `Future.get(long,TimeUnit)` resumes. Task continues to be executed.

Comment: Then tell the executor to shut down.

Comment: @yair If a thread is doing work you don't want it to do, then that thread's code is broken and should be fixed. Code needs to cooperate, not be at war with one piece of code struggling to control some other piece of code that's taking rogue actions that are unwanted.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you cannot always guarantee that a given piece of work will finish within X seconds - one example is a scarce operating system resource - so you need _some_ way of being able to abort it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I would rephrase it is, "it has to provide some way for you to abort it". If some operation must be abortable, then whatever performs that operation must have a way to abort that operation. If not, it's broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That would certainly be nice, but  you do not always have the luxury of being able to do so.  What is the problem with using Executors exactly as they are designed to be used?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you cannot always shutdown the *whole* executor just because one of the threads is stuck... And I think these details should be part of the answer. Apparently, though, OP begs to differ :).

Comment: @yair sure you cannot.  But in this particular case you can.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yup. So it seems.

Comment: @yair well, the "accept flag" is to be given to the answer which the OP considers the most helpful, not the most detailed or the most correct or the first or any other reason.  Typically the community upvotes the best answers over time regardless if they were the accepted one or not.  If your answers do not get chosen as selected answer or as many upvotes as you want, then it may be improvable by wording your answers differently.  I have noticed that Jon Skeet writes very clearly and succinct and as a result get a lot of upvotes and accepts.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen we share the same opinion :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timeouts for your blocking calls.  If there are no timeouts, abstract the call and time it out that way.

You could create 1 thread the poll the task for its completion status, and kill it if its exceeded some value.  The task itself would still require yet another thread.  I'd do this by creating tasks which have a `staleness` value. Poll all tasks periodically, if they are stale, cancel them.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1: If you put your code in a try block with a wait() statement you can catch interruptedException which will then follow to your finally. Another thread will have to send a notify() or notifyAll() to cause the interruption whenever circumstances need to interrupt your thread.

Suggestion 2: I'm only just a beginner with Java but the thread getting stuck means you must be able to throw a custom exception inside your try/finally block.

Comment: You might find the concurrent additions to Java 5 interesting.  Using threads directly is hard to do 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

Best solution is to send your data with a timeout. Should look something like

```
try {
    mySendingDataLibraryApi.sendData(data, timeout /*, timeUnit */);
        // some new APIs enable also to configure the time unit of the required timeout.
        // Older APIs typically just use milliseconds.
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    doCleanup(); // your cleanup method.
}
```

**(2)**

If this isn't applicable since the API you're using doesn't expose such configuration, second best solution would be to use an interruptible API `sendData` method and interrupt the executing thread. This relies on the fact that such an interruptible API is provided. I wouldn't count much on the existence of such a method if a timed method isn't provided by the API... Anyway, the code in the thread that executes the task would look like:

```
class MySendingDataRunnable implements Runnable {    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mySendingDataLibraryApi.sendDataInterruptibly(data);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            doCleanup(); // your cleanup method.
            // here either re-throw InterruptedExecption
            // or restore the interrupted state with Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the caller the thread, should use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instance returned by its [`Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) method, in order to wait the desired time and cancel the task with the `mayInterruptIfRunning` argument set to `true`:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
final Future<?> future = executor.submit(new MySendingDataRunnable());
try {
    final Object noResult = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // no result for Runnable
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // here again either re-throw or restore interupted state
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // some applicative exception has occurred and should be handled
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    future.cancel(true); // *** here you actually cancel the task after time is out
}
```

**(3)**

If the API you use provide neither of these features (timed / interruptible methods), you'll have to use your creativity! This one line of blocking code of yours must be blocking *on some resource*. Try to reach out for this resource and shut it down or disconnect from it, implicitly causing the task to terminate. A typical example is closing a network connection.

---

**Note:** the above solutions only provide a way of actually cancelling the task and freeing the thread for further tasks. **The thread might still be alive though.** Killing the thread is usually not something that you do when a task is completed (or failed for that matter). It is acceptable when you've created some thread(s) for specific task(s) which isn't supposed to be executed ever again. In such cases you use the above `ExecutorService` and invoke its [`shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) method. <sub>And even `shutdownNow()` only makes best effort and typically depends on the the actual task to be interruptible...</sub>

[Here's a detailed article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) (somewhat old but nonetheless).