# How to use Object.wait(long) in java?

Tags: java, wait

I'm now trying to add an update checking module into my program. The method is processing a website for update informations. But in some situations the website is not accessable, and the program stops checking in 0.5 seconds. To make this possible, I wrote these code:

```java
int[] lock = new int[0];
boolean fileListGot = false;

Thread downloadFile = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            fileList = HttpFetcher.fetch("http://*****/****");
            fileListGot = true;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
};

synchronized (lock) {
    downloadFile.start();
    lock.wait(500);
}

return fileListGot;
```

But the program doesn't stop after 0.5 seconds. What the wrong with the program? And how to use Object.wait(long)?

Comment: Have you started by reading its javadoc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread

Comment: May be you are forget to  "downloadFile.start()"...
Without this your new thread will not be start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Object.notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) javadocs - the important part being "The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. "

The main thread acquires the monitor of `lock`. It starts the worker thread. The worker thread attempts to gain `lock`'s monitor, but cannot. The main thread then calls `lock.wait(500)` and so loses the monitor. The worker thread then gains the monitor and proceeds. If the download is still going on after 500ms, wait returns and the main thread attempts to gain the monitor, but it is still owned the worker thread.

You don't need to hold the monitor when downloading the file, only when mutating the shared variables - try this instead

```
public void run() {
    T temp = HttpFetcher.fetch("http://*****/****");
    synchronized (lock) {
        fileList = temp;
        fileListGot = true;
        lock.notify();
    }
}
```

where T is the appropriate type for fileList

Comment: You're absolutely right! But I do not agree with your solution. Although it will cause the method to return after 500ms, it does not abort the fetch operation itself. So I'd suggest using something like that: http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings/TimedRun.java

Answer (score 0):

You enter synchronized block then start a thread. The thread's run tries to enter synchronized block and waits forever because you have already taken the same lock from another thread.

Move `downloadFile.start()` away from synchronized block.