# How to run a Java program for a specific amount of time?

Tags: java

I want to run my program on a list of files. But a few files take much longer than expected time. So I want to kill the thread/process after the timeout period, and run the program on next file. Is there any easy way to do it? I'll be running only one thread at a time.

Edit1:

I am sorry I couldn't make it clear earlier. Here is the `for` loop code.

```
for (File file : files)
{
  //Perform operations. 

}
```

So a file is Java program file which can contain many methods. If the number of methods are less, my analysis works fine. If there are many say 20 methods, it keeps executing and analyzing them for a few hours. So in the latter case, I would like to finish that execution and go for the next java file.

And I don't have any constraint of single threading. If multi-threading works, it's still good for me. Thanks.

Comment: While processing any one file, are there points at which you can check the time-spent? For example, each time you have read another 10,000 lines, or something like that?

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded program?

Comment: single threaded only. I just need to stop execution after some time and kill all the resources it is using, and move to the next file.

Comment: @DariusX. Yes. I can find the time within that execution but I am not sure how it'll help?

Comment: Well, if "analyzing the file" means reading its lines, and if that means a loop, and if you know that you get about 10 iterations per second, then.... after every 600 iterations [est. 1 minute] you can check the time, and quit if it is over 10 minutes.

Comment: Not using threads for a problem like this is trying to fit a round peg into a square hole. It can be done, it just won't be pretty. Is there a reason you can't use threads? Like, are you absolutely *sure* you can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kinds of things are usually done multi-threaded. For an example, see [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread) .

As you commented though, you are looking for a single-threaded solution. That is best done by periodically checking if the timeout expired yet. Some thread will have to do the checking, and since you requested it to have only one thread, the checking will have to be somewhere halfway in the code.

Let's say that the majority of the time spent is in a while-loop that reads the file line-by-line. You could do something like this:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(System.nanoTime() - start > 600E9) { //More than 10 minutes past the start.
        throw new Exception("Timeout!");
    }
    ... //Process the line.
}
```

Comment: I think this is a nice way to solve the problem. However did you have a reason in mind for choosing nanoTime() instead of currentTimeMillis() was the choice arbitrary ?

Comment: Processing a single line is not likely to take very long. You might want to perform the time check every hundred lines or so, just to cut down on the system calls.

Comment: Also, as OP's requirements have changed and he can use multi-threading, could you give a simple example of this? Say, making a `ProcessFile` class that implements `Runnable` and is executed by an `ExecutorService` or somesuch?

Comment: @Anupam: I arbitrarily chose `nanoTime()` since I know it best from microbenchmarking stuff. I expect `currentTimeMillis()` could be slightly better for this case if it has less overhead, since exact timing is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a quick example of how you would do this using multi-threading:

First we make a `Runnable` for processing the `File`

```
class ProcessFile implements Runnable {
    File file;
    public ProcessFile(File file){
        this.file = file;
    }
    public void run(){
        //process the file here
    }
}
```

Next we actually execute that class as a thread:

```
class FilesProcessor {

    public void processFiles(){
        //I guess you get the files somewhere in here
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ProcessFile process;
        Future future;
        for (File file : files) {
            process = new ProcessFile(file);
            future = executor.submit(process);
            try {
                future.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                System.out.println("completed file");
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("file processing timed out");
            }
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

So we iterate through each file and process it. If it takes longer than 10 minutes, we get a timeout exception and the thread dies. Easy as pie.

Comment: Thanks man for the clean code. I was trying the code in a similar way with the link given by GhostKeeper. So I accepted his answer. Please dont mind :)

Comment: @Junaid No worries, he had a good answer and a useful link. Glad this could be of use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a while or for loop for processing these files what about reading a timer each loop turn.

You can measure how long you are processing data with:

```
 while(....){
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // ... the code being measured ...    
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
 }
```

Or maybe starting chronometer before loop i don't know

**EDIT :**
So if you have one loop turn by file you have to put somme time measure at some specific point in your code like said darius.

For example :

```
   for each file
           start = System.currentTimeMillis();
           //do some treatment
           elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
           // do a more tratment
           elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Comment: The problem is that code actually analyzes a file. Sometimes it takes a few hours to finish. I want to run it only for 10 minutes. If it's not finished, kill it and move to the next file.

Comment: If you can't make an other thread to measure elapsed time you have to measure time elapsed at some point like said Darius. But I think a better solution is with an other thread like said MirroredFate