# How to stop an ExecutorService completely?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922833/how-to-run-a-java-program-for-a-specific-amount-of-time) on SO and got a solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread). But after running that solution, it seems not working as desired.

To rephrase, I am iterating over a bunch of Java files and analyzing them one by one. My analysis algorithm may take from 1 second to 5-10 hours, may be. But I want to finish the analysis if it's not finished by 10 minutes. The program also generates out of memory exception if it is kept running for long time.

Here is the code I am using.

For loop:

```
for (File file : files)
{
String fileName = file.getName();
String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Task ts = new Task(filePath);
Future<String> future = executor.submit(ts);
try {
    System.out.println("@@ Started.. " + fileName );
    System.out.println(future.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    System.out.println("@@ Finished!" + fileName);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("@@ Terminated!" + fileName);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executor, future);
    future.cancel(true);
}
}
```

shutdownAndAwaitTermination(,) method:

```
// http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
public static void  shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool, Future<String> futureObj) {
       pool.shutdown(); 
       try {
         if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
           pool.shutdownNow(); 
           if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           {
               System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
           }
         }
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
         pool.shutdownNow();
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       }
     }

}
```

Task class:

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    String fName = "";
    Task(String file)
    {
        fName = file;
    }
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        {
    // Long running program on file fName.          
       }
        return "Ready!";
    }
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
@@ Started.. file1.java
@@ Terminated!file1.java
Pool did not terminate
@@ Started.. file2.java
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:119)
    at controller.Controller.main(Controller.java:75)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at iterator.CFGIterator.combineCFGs(CFGIterator.java:137)
    at iterator.CFGIterator.setOneCFG(CFGIterator.java:92)
    at iterator.CFGIterator.<init>(CFGIterator.java:41)
    at cfg.ClassObj.iterator(ClassObj.java:47)
    at taintanalyzer.TaintAnalyzer.analyze(TaintAnalyzer.java:196)
    at cfg.ClassObj.accept(ClassObj.java:65)
    at taintanalyzer.TaintAnalyzer.analyze(TaintAnalyzer.java:348)
    at controller.Task.call(Controller.java:140)
    at controller.Task.call(Controller.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: You seem to have an `ConcurrentModificationException` inside the `// Long running program`.

Comment: When I run separately on file2, it does not give me this exception. I guess, file1 process is not being terminated/killed and is still using the resources.

Comment: We can't help unless you show what it's doing (a small reproducible example would be best.)

Comment: It's basically a static taint analysis algorithm which is run on that file. Not sure how much code I can paste here. And it's a research tool, so can't share the logic much.

Comment: If you post more of the stack trace, or look at it, it'll tell you where it happens. Otherwise, Can you prove that it has anything to do with the unfinished `ExecutorService`?

Comment: If I run the program on file2, it does not generate exception but if file1 is run before file2, it generates concurrency exception. Anyway, I have updated stack trace. Please have a look.

Comment: See in `iterator.CFGIterator.combineCFGs`, you seem to be using an `Iterator` to iterate over an `ArrayList` but modifying the `ArrayList` directly. This will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. See all the related links on Stackoverflow. Can't help any more than that without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here :

```
for (File file : files) { //... }
```

I guess that you uses `ArrayList<File>` to hold many objects File. However, the datastructure `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

[ArrayList Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally

Instead of `ArrayList`, you can try using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to deal with a large list and get the performance.

EDIT :

If you want to see first file finish running and insist on using awaiTermination, you need to set the timeout parameter to be big enough.

```
   pool.shutdown(); 
   try {
     // Wait longer, example 6000 seconds for existing task to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); 
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
       {
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
       }
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     pool.shutdownNow();
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```

Comment: Nothing in the code posted shows it being modified.

Comment: Yes. True that. But the problem for me is how to stop the first thread which is still executing in the backend.

Comment: I mean, when we call shutdownNow() and future.cancel(), that process should release all the resources (ArrayList etc.) And when it is run on file2, it should make a fresh start. When process is run alone, it works fine. but in a sequence, it causes concurrency error because previous process has not released all the resources.