# How can I cancel a Task after a timeout?

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx, javafx-8

I have some `Task` execute a I/O blocking operation that can hang (fetching a file from an `URL`)

```
task = new Task<List<WSDLOperation>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<WSDLOperation> call() {
                List<WSDLOperation> services = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    services = WSDLService.createService(wsdlURL).getOperations();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Can't reach {0}", wsdlURL);
                }
                return services;
            }
        };

    }
```

The method `createService` can wait forever without throwing any `Exception`.
(I execute the task using a global (`static public`)`ExecutorService` defined in Main class).

Comment: It looks like the problem is in createService method. Methods that can hang forever should throw interrupted exception, else it's hard to kill it (you can always call System.exit which is a bad practice - it kills the whole jvm ). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java in case you haven't yet.

Comment: `createService` is  a third-part method, I have no control on it, is there any method to associate the `Task` with some timeout ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the api documentation?

Comment: `Future` might help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread

Comment: It seems that the operation fires an `Exception` After a long timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How use future and cancel task after timeout:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Task t = new Task();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(t);

        try {
            System.out.println("Started..");
            System.out.println(future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // throws
                                                                    // TimeoutException
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Terminated!");
        }
    }
}

class Task implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("task running!");
        }
        return "Ready!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here the `future.cancel(true)` in `TimeoutException` handling part will just set the interrupt flag of future thread to `true` right? It wouldn't guarantee the future actually stops and kills the task in progress.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `ExecutorService`, so you can do it after submitting the task:

```
ExecutorService executor = // ...  
Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // timeout 5 mins
```

Comment: That still won't kill the task itself. It just means the caller gives up on the blocking `get`. If `createService` is interruptible the caller could try `future.cancel(true)` but otherwise they're out of luck.

Comment: Calling `future.get` on the `javafx` thread will bock the UI.