# Java kill thread after some time or when return data from him

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I kill a thread if the time for him over or it return me the data?

- how I start it
- I need to pass a arg for him

Comment: How did you start the thread in question?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Not a duplicate. Modern Java conventions discourage you from creating `Thread` objects explicitly, so knowing how to kill one is not necessarily useful. `Thread` <> all kinds of threads. If you view this question as "How can I cancel an async task after a certain timeout?" (and [it's certain plausible that's what they wanted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), the advise in those answers is basically not helpful.

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate. Feel free to link more questions.

Comment: I want to kill it if it not return data after 10 second

Comment: There are 4 different questions (how to create a thread, how to pass an arg to a thread, how to kill a thread, how to get data from a thread) - all of them are too broad. Could you share the code you have written for this? What problems exactly do you have?

Comment: Yes I need to create a thread that has all the 4 options

Comment: @JohnKugelman Once again, those are all specific to `java.lang.Thread` which you should not be using. The closest I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027314/how-can-i-cancel-a-task-after-a-timeout) but the answers aren't particularly great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Future.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) with a timeout.

If the timeout is exceeded, you'll get a `TimeoutException`, which you can handle any way you like.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Main
{
    private static int foo(final int arg)
    {
        /* Uncomment to see future get interrupted
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000); 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { } */

        return 1000 + arg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
    {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(() -> Main.foo(3));

        try
        {
            int result = future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            future.cancel(true);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's tell me "cannot resolve method 'submit'"

Comment: I've added the imports in case you've imported the wrong thing. If you're not on Java 8, you'll need to convert the lambda expression to an anonymous `Callable<Integer>`.