# How do I stop this Thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

While learning using Threads in Android I've created simple thread that updates time textview every second:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(time!=0){
                                if(time>9){timeLeftTV.setText("0:"+time);}
                                else{timeLeftTV.setText("0:0"+time);}
                                time--;
                            }
                            else {
                                //timeLeftTV.setText("finished");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

I want to display dialog box when the time expires. How do I stop this thread?

Comment: Use t.interrupt(); to stop thread where you want to stop it.

Comment: use this myService.getThread().interrupt();

Comment: thread.stop method is deprecated @Shane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

This is example of 30 seconds for 1 second time interval.

You can display dialog box on `onFinish()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I use a `Runnable` that can be scheduled with a `Handler` as followed:

```
final int timeInterval = 1000;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run () {

    textView.setText("time..");

    // schedule the same Runnable after one second
    handler.postDelayed(this, timeInterval); 
  }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeInterval);
```

To stop your loop, remove the `Runnable` from the `Handler`:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

When you don't want to use the method above, simply use a `Boolean` that prevents your loop to continue and your `Thread` will end itself:

```
boolean stop = false;
Thread t = new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run () {

    while (!stop) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
};
t.start();
```

To stop the `Thread`:

```
stop = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just interrupt the thread, Where you want to stop it.

```
thread.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to stop thread.
Like you can use [Executor Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of timer. But for the quick solution you can go ahead with the following one:

long startTimer= System.currentTimeMillis();
long stopTimer= startTimer+ 60*1000; // 60 seconds * 1000 ms/sec

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < stopTimer)
{
    // Perform your all the required operation here
}
```

Hope it will help you.

For Executor service check the below stack link:

[How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)