# Want to run the method again if its taking time first time. How to achieve it?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a method (say execute()), if it takes more than 10 secs(per say)to return response  i need to reexecute it.

Kindly help me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Google: circuit breaking, retries, timeouts and exponential backoff. Each one of these terms will help you understand better what is relevant to your use-case.

Comment: If you have a future, you can call get with a timeout.

Comment: @assylias
is it related to Executor Service.
Kindly point me to a reference or example

Comment: Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275596/6138873, this is almost what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Object response;
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
response = execute();
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 10000) {
  response = execute();
}
```

? or

```
Object get() {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<Object> response = executor.submit(() -> {
    return execute();
  });
  executor.shutdown();
  executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  if (executor.isTerminated()) {
    return response.get();
  }
  executor.shutdownNow();
  return get();
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will solve the problem
I have to kill the line 3 if it is taking more than intended time