# my java program get stuck on Transport.send(message) line

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have an application, user requests report and gets it in her inbox as zipped csv file attachment.
It works fine for sending emails with zip file with max ~ 44kb. But program get stuck forever on 
Transport.send(message); line, while sending reports with bigger size.

I search similar issues and applied the timeout solution, but it does not help me.

```
    try {
        Properties props = mailProperties.asProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", TIMEOUT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", TIMEOUT);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(mailProperties.getUsername(), mailProperties.getPassword());
            }
        });
        session.setDebug(true);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.getFrom()));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mail.getTo()));
        message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setText(mail.getText());
        MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp2.attachFile(filePath);
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
        message.setContent(mp);
        Transport.send(message);  // get stuck here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error : ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Sending email failed.", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to put this method in a threaded task? If the threaded task takes longer than expected, timeout the thread?

[How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm looking for a solution, to be able to send all report mails requested by user, and wonder about why some can not be sen't and if the problem is related with size or not.

Comment: It's not a really good answer. I should have made my answer a comment. 

So I see that you have set the timeouts - I'm surprised you are not returning at least a timeout exception. However, I don't see the construction of Transport. Is the Transport part of the Session?

Could you use: 

Transport transport = session.getTransport(); 
transport.send(...)