# Java timeout function is not working for my below codes

Tags: java

I tried to set a 1-second time limit for my SQL query in Java, using the methods:
[How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread/2275596#2275596)

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());

        try {
            System.out.println("Started..");
            System.out.println(future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Terminated!");
        }

        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}

class Task implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            // some codes to do query via SQL Server JDBC, assuming it takes 10 seconds.
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            // some codes to print the query result
        return "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found that though it prints 'Terminated' after 1 second, the program keeps running and prints the query result after 10 seconds. What's the reason why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: As mentioned in the question you linked, you have to check `Thread.interrupted()` inside your `call()` method. If it is set to `true` you return the method immediately and don't print/use the result anymore.

Comment: @Progman Thanks. But how would I do this. It's just a single line of code runs about 10s. (If I'm running a for loop that may run for a long time, I may check interrupted for each iteration, but this is not the case).

Comment: If the method you are calling does not check the `Thread.interrupted()` call itself you have to wait for it to finish. But **you** can still check `Thread.interrupted()` after the long running call and decide not to do you actions you normally would do (like printing the result set).

Comment: @Progman Actually we want to raise an exception if there is a time out. (Rather than 'wait until finish and decide what to do'

Comment: As mentioned by "Joe C" you can use `setQueryTimeout()` to set the timeout before calling `executeQuery()`. But since you said it didn't work for you, you might need to edit your question to include the full source code you have (with the `setQueryTimeout()` call) and how exactly it "isn't working".

Comment: @Progman Not sure what counts towards the setquerytimeout, t(server execution) or t(server execution) + t(send data to my local machine). Might be the case when server finishes query quickly but need some time to send my data back.

Answer (score 3):

`shutdownNow` doesn't actually stop a thread, it merely sends a signal (an interrupt) that the Thread can act upon. Stopping a Thread in Java is tricky because while you *can* just kil the thread (with `Thread.stop`), you really shouldn't because you have no idea what state the Thread is in and what it will leave behind.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()).

Comment: How could I do that with thread.stop(). Sorry that I'm new to Java. Also, will GC still work to collect the gabbage if I force to kill a thread.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `cancel` on a future does not guarantee that the job will be cancelled.  It depends on the method checking periodically for interrupts, and then aborting if an interrupt is detected.  `Statement.execute()` does not do that.

In your case, given you are executing a SQL statement, there is a method in the `Statement` class ([`setQueryTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-)) which achieves what you appear to be after without over-engineering timeouts by other means.

Comment: Thanks. that's very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark a best answer.

Answer (score -1):

Another way you can approach this is by using the thread.sleep() method. I often use it when I want my program to simply pause for a short or long period of time. In the parameters, you put values in thousands that correspond to seconds. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException // Required for thread.sleep()
{
    System.out.println("Hi there.");
    Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait two seconds before running the next line of code
    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
}
```

This is quite basic, but can be used for more than just strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are attempting to solve a different problem to the one the OP is asking about.  The OP doesn't want to pause his program, but to stop an operation if it hasn't completed within a certain length of time.

Comment: @JoeC Oh I see, sorry for the mistake. I'm trying to understand and teach to help myself learn at the same time.