# Time limit for Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring-batch

How can I set time limit for a job? Basically, I would like to fail the job after 10 minutes.

Comment: You can set a time-limit for a threaded task using an `ExecutorService`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread