# How to get time out exception for fetch location from Location service

Tags: android

```
public class LocationUtils {

    private static final long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 5000L;
    private static final float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 300;
    LocationListener mLocationListener;
    public void fetchLocation(Context context, LocationCallback callback) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (callback != null && location != null) {
                String locationString = getLocationString(location);
                Timber.i("LocationUtils = " + locationString);
                callback.onLocationLocked(locationString);
                removeListener(locationManager);
                return;
            }

            if (mLocationListener == null) {
                mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        removeListener(locationManager);
                        if (callback != null) {
                            String locationString = getLocationString(location);
                            if (locationString != null) {
                                Timber.i("LocationUtils = " + locationString);
                                callback.onLocationLocked(locationString);
                            } else {
                                callback.onLocationLockFailed(new LocationNotFoundException());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                };
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
                        LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            removeListener(locationManager);
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onLocationLockFailed(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeListener(LocationManager locationManager){
        try {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        mLocationListener = null;
    }

    private String getLocationString(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            return location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public interface LocationCallback {
        void onLocationLocked(String location);

        void onLocationLockFailed(Exception e);
    }

    public class LocationNotFoundException extends Exception {

    }
}
```

This is my code i want to get one more method time out exception so that if Location Service will not able to fetch location then that timeout exception should be invoked and accordingly we can handle it but there  is not overrides method for timeout in location service please suggest me how we will implement this using time or timer class in android

Answer (score 0):

please try following it will help you

```
public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) {
    switch( status ) {
    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                // ....show message
        break;
    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                // ...show message
        break;
    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                // ...show message
        break;
    }
}
```

and show message accordingly

Comment: I am unable to find LocationProvider class can you please suggest me in this ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ganesh looks good and the intended way of doing it, but if you want to configure your own timeout, maybe you can use this answer to this question: [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

So you create an independent thread to call fetch location and if the timeout expires you can do whatever you want (probably you need to remove the listener, as well)