# Is it possible to force Java to throw an Exception after some block of code runs longer than acceptable?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, thread-safety, wait

I have a block of code, while executing code it will generate popup window, if we click manually then it will process, because of that it is waiting long time, I Would like to introduce timeout function here, can suggest please?

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime();
        process.waitFor(); //need to introduce Timeout here.
        returnValue = process.exitValue();
        if (returnValue != -1) {
        return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
```

if didnt get response within time frame then forget it, and it should return false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Process.waitFor(long,TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the subprocess represented by this Process object has terminated, or the specified waiting time elapses.

Comment: If add process.waitFor(long, TimeUnit) getting an compilation error like, Undefined reference: boolean Process.waitFor(long, TimeUnit) ;  

Failed to execute Goal: animal-sniffer-maven-plugin