# how to run one thread after complete another thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to run two threads `r1`, and `r2`. First start the `r1` and after completion of `r1`, start `r2` (only after the completion `r1`). How can this be done, two threads, one after another?

Comment: can u plz post your code that what had you done till now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592716/multithreading-question/4593265#4593265) has an example using a `Thread` and a `Handler`.  This method might be useful if you wanted to perform some UI updates in between the threads running.

Comment: Dave I was about to forward him to the same link +1 for  linking

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do all the tasks you want in one single thread? This way they will be "naturally" one after the other.

The way to implement this depends on what type of tasks you want to do and how you pass them the information they require to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join() method for this.

Answer (score -3):

1. Make a Boolean variable with initially false
2. Start the first thread
3. After completion of the entire 1st thread  execution  make the Boolean value to true
4. Don't start second thread util/unless the flag becomes true