# java start one background thread after another complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I saw this question: [how to run one thread after complete another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884957/how-to-run-one-thread-after-complete-another-thread)  , but the answer to it is not appropriate for me.

I have such kind of java code for Android:

```
public void startTask(Runnable r)
    {
        running = true;
        Log.i(tag, "-----------start.Runnable-----------");

        Thread first = new Thread(r);
        first.start();

        Thread second = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                running = false;
            }
        });
}
```

first `Thread` takes as param `Runnable` object with some hard operation which I am processing in background service. So, when I call method: **startTask()** I set **running = true;** to prevent double executing tasks. But, also, I need right after completeness of first thread start second thread to set **running = false;** to enable other operations to execute.

**How can I wait completeness of first thread by second not to freeze main thread?? Thanks!**

Comment: Why not use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? It has method `onPostExecute` in that method you can easily start another `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Thread first = new Thread(r);
first.start();

Thread second = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        first.join();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        running = false;
    }
});
second.start();
```

I changed:

- add final keyworrd for 'first'
- wait finish of first thread by #join at begin of second thread.
- start sencond thread soon.

Answer (score 7):

You may use `SingleThreadExecutor`.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(runnable1);
executor.execute(runnable2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this variant is workable too, but I can't check both as right variant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Android programmer but something like this may work:

```
private volatile boolean running = false;

public void startTask(final Runnable r)
{
    running = true;
    Log.i(tag, "-----------start.Runnable-----------");

    Runnable runme = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                r.run();
            } finally {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(runme).start();
}
```

It needs only one thread to run the task and then clear the `running` flag. Note the use of `volatile` in the declaration of `running`, as this variable is being read and written from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this way, but it does not work in appropriate way. When I press hardware BACK button -- it runs finally not in that way I need.