# how to cancel the uploading file from gallery to server

Tags: android, uploading

This is the code to upload image from my gallery to server this code is working.

But while clicking back button its loading.

Now what i am asking means when i click back button it should go to previous page and the upload should stop.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
package com.politicalmileage.chintamanvanga;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContributeToTheSite extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contributetothesite);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://url";
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);

        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContributeToTheSite.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start(); 

        }           

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);
            uploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n Thanks for Your Contribution to the Mobile App";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(ContributeToTheSite.this, "Thanks for Your Contribution to the Mobile App.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                             
                                finish();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(ContributeToTheSite.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(ContributeToTheSite.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }

}
```

Comment: use a handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html and then u can stop handler whenever you want, but be aware it doesn't guarente that it doesn't uploaded. And you can take a look to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: hi can u give me the small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;     

    if (conn != null)
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onBackPressed() method of your activity to stop the upload thread when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.
First, you must override `public void onBackPressed()` Method.

```
     else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContributeToTheSite.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         uploadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);

             }
           }).start(); 

    }
```

uploadThread is define in class or static for use in onBackPressed method.
After then, `uploadThread.stop()` where in onBackPressed method.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
uploadThread.stop();
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If this way is not possible, try this.

```
public class ContributeToTheSite extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private boolean sendingFile = false;  
...
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0==btnselectpic)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);

    }
    else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContributeToTheSite.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         sendingFile = true;
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);

             }
           }).start(); 

    }           

} 

public void onBackPressed(){
sendingFile = false;
super.onBackPressed();
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
...
while (bytesRead > 0 && sendingFile ) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }
if( !sendingFile ){
  //to do send message server sending file is canceled.
  return -1;
}
sendingFile = false;
...
...
```

Comment: its not working can u tell me the how to use this i am new in android

Comment: @user3374790 show my edited answer. This way is cancel sending file, but you control this situation in server.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can interrupt current thread from the following method define in below so questions.    [How to stop threads and handlers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923159/how-to-stop-threads-and-handlers-in-android)
 **i think instead of creating thread you have to use asynctask and cancel current asynctask it is very easy to handle**
  [asynctask cancel method java doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)