# How to kill a thread running in a new activity

Tags: android, multithreading

So activity starts and I create a Thread which checks when to go to the next activity. But sometimes I need this activity to kill itself. onPause does this, but after that Thread is still alive and after time runs out it start a new activity. Is it possible to kill this Thread and stop goToFinals intent?

```
 public class Questions extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String in = getIntent().getStringExtra("time");         
        long tmp = Long.parseLong(in);
        endTime = (long) System.currentTimeMillis() + tmp;

        Thread progress = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                while(endTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Intent goToFinals = new Intent(Questions.this,End.class);
                        startActivity(goToFinals);
            }

        });
        progress.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can stop your thread.  If you store your `Thread` object then you can call `interrupt()` on it:

```
 progress.interrupt();
```

This would cause the `sleep()` to throw an `InterruptedException` which you should return from, not just print the stack trace.  You should also do the loop like:

```
 while(endTime > System.currentTimeMillis()
     && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

You could also set some sort of shutdown flag:

```
// it must be volatile if used in multiple threads
private volatile boolean shutdown;

// in your thread loop you do:
while (!shutdown && endTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    ...
}

// when you want the thread to stop:
shutdown = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to safely quit the thread you must first call thread_instance.interrupt() and then you can check if it is interrupted or not.
Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java) post for kill java thread.The way they recomend is to use a shared variable as a flag which asks the background thread to stop. This variable can then be set by a different object requesting the thread terminate.