# How to stop a thread created by implementing runnable interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have created class by implementing runnable interface and then created many threads(nearly 10) in some other class of my project.
How to stop some of those threads?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to `interrupt()` it, which will cause `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to return `true`, and may also throw an `InterruptedException` under certain circumstances where the Thread is *waiting*, for example `Thread.sleep()`, `otherThread.join()`, `object.wait()` etc.

Inside the `run()` method you would need catch that exception and/or regularly check the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` value and do something (for example, break out).

Note: Although `Thread.interrupted()` seems the same as `isInterrupted()`, it has a nasty side effect: Calling `interrupted()` **clears** the `interrupted` flag, whereas calling `isInterrupted()` does not.

Other non-interrupting methods involve the use of "stop" (`volatile`) flags that the running Thread monitors.

Comment: I don't have a `while` in my Thread, but I still sometimes need to stop it before it process all lines inside `run` method

Answer (score 44):

> How to stop a thread created by implementing runnable interface?

There are many ways that you can stop a thread but all of them take specific code to do so.  A typical way to stop a thread is to have a `volatile boolean shutdown` field that the thread checks every so often:

```
  // set this to true to stop the thread
  volatile boolean shutdown = false;
  ...
  public void run() {
      while (!shutdown) {
          // continue processing
      }
  }
```

You can also interrupt the thread which causes `sleep()`, `wait()`, and some other methods to throw `InterruptedException`.  You also should test for the thread interrupt flag with something like:

```
  public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          // continue processing
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // good practice
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              return;
          }
      }
  }
```

Note that that interrupting a thread with `interrupt()` will *not* necessarily cause it to throw an exception immediately.  Only if you are in a method that is interruptible will the `InterruptedException` be thrown.

If you want to add a `shutdown()` method to your class which implements `Runnable`, you should define your own class like:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean shutdown;
    public void run() {
        while (!shutdown) {
            ...
        }
    }
    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my class i have written a method which sets flag(shutdown in your example) to true.But i am unable to access this method from the other class where i need to stop the thread.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to expose it somehow.  I usually do something like `public class MyClass implements Runnable { volatile boolean shutdown; public void run() { if (! shutdown) { ... } } }`.  You could add a `shutdown()` method which sets the shutdown flag.  Then you would do `new Thread(new MyClass()).start();` to run it.

Comment: I don't have a `while` in my Thread, but I still sometimes need to stop it before it process all lines inside `run` method

Comment: Then you can use an `if` @user25.  I'd spend the time to ask a full question if you want more help.

Answer (score 13):

*Stopping* the thread in midway using `Thread.stop()` is not a good practice. More appropriate way is to make the thread return programmatically. Let the Runnable object use a shared variable in the `run()` method. Whenever you want the thread to stop, use that variable as a flag.

EDIT: Sample code

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    
    private volatile Boolean stop = false;
    
    public void run(){
        
        while(!stop){
            
            //some business logic
        }
    }
    public Boolean getStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    public void setStop(Boolean stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }       
}

public class TestStop {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        Thread th = new Thread(myThread);
        th.start();
        
        //Some logic goes there to decide whether to 
        //stop the thread or not. 
        
        //This will compell the thread to stop
        myThread.setStop(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my class i have written a method which sets flag to false.But i am unable to access this method from the other class where i need to stop the thread.

Comment: Assuming that the class which created the thread is responsible for stopping it, a reference to the Runnable instance should be maintained in this class and using this reference, the method to set the flag should be called.

Comment: If you don't mind can you give little more clarity with an example

Comment: You should make your `stop` variable volatile.

Comment: What if I want to cancel in the middle of `some bussiness logic` , wouldn't this make it run the "whole business logic" anyway? Because the flag is being checked at next iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and you use [submit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, it will give you a `Future` back. You can call [cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the returned Future to stop your `Runnable` task.

Comment: cancel attempts to cancel the execution but doesn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

Stopping (Killing) a thread mid-way is not recommended. The API is actually deprecated.

However, you can get more details including workarounds here: [How do you kill a Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

> **Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() is superbly working.   but this
>   code is only pause the timer.**
>
> **This code is stop and reset the thread timer.**
>   **h1 is handler name.**
>   This code is add on inside your button click listener.
>   w_h =minutes w_m =milli sec i=counter

```
 i=0;
            w_h = 0;
            w_m = 0;


            textView.setText(String.format("%02d", w_h) + ":" + String.format("%02d", w_m));
                        hl.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();


                        }


                    });


                }`
```