# Android terminate run thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I use this code for find all runnable thread

And i want terminate this thread but my code not working

How i can ?

```
for (Thread t: Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    if (t.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
        t.stop();
        //Thread.interrupted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is` t.getState()` returning a valid value?  Try just outputting that to make sure that you are retrieving any threads at all.

Comment: Yes this code return all thread

Comment: Please see this thread on implementing your own proper stop method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630737/how-to-stop-a-thread-created-by-implementing-runnable-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate class that implements Runnable and do this:

```
public class GameLoopThread implements Runnable {

private GameView view;
private boolean running = false;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
    this.view = view;
    surfaceHolder = view.getHolder();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (running) {
        c = null;
        try {
            c = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                //draw your stuff
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) { running = run; }
}
```

So to create the Thread, you would do

```
GameLoopThread gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
Thread t = new Thread(gameLoopThread);
```

And when you want to stop it:

```
gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
```

Basically it's a custom Thread that has a way to stop it.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you're asking

Comment: gameLoopThread.setRunning(false) stops the thread. Also, gameLoopThread is NOT a thread, it is a Runnable. You still make a thread the regular way, but with gameLoopThread as the parameter (above)