# How can I stop/pause particular thread from ExecutorService?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have `spring scheduler` method. And `ExecutorService`

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000) 
    public void startSchedule() throws IOException{
threadPool.submit(() -> {
            if(.......)return;
            try {
                generate(reportTasck);
            } catch (NurException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
          }
```

Each 5 sec start my method and if a necessary condition - start new thread with my logic. How can I stop/pause particular thread?

I have button on veb page, and if I press it I need to stop my thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is already quite some discussion on SO regarding the stopping of threads. For a variety of reasons you should not stop or kill a thread as e.g. noted here:

[How do you kill a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

In order to allow the thread to properly cleanup its resources it should be the thread's responsibility to terminate itself by e.g. periodically checking some condition using e.g. a shared variable or via the thread's interrupt flag. See this answer for more details:

[How to stop a thread created by implementing runnable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630737/how-to-stop-a-thread-created-by-implementing-runnable-interface)