# How can I STOP this animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, imagebutton, runnable

I created a color background animation that starts on button click (it smoothly changes the background color over and over again). **My problem is that I can't stop the animation** (if I click the button again it increases the animation speed). I already tried to create a while-loop but then the animation did't work anymore. My goal is that the animation starts if I press the image Btn, and if I press it again it should stop.

**Code:**

```
imageButton_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

                // Handler and runnable to run the animation in devices sdk below honeycomb.
                final Handler handler = new Handler();

                Runnable ChangeBackgroundRunnable = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        number++;
                        float[] hsvColor = {0, 1, 1};
                        hsvColor[0] = 360f * number / 100;
                        color.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvColor));

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 80);
                        if (number >=100)
                            number = 1;
                    }
                };
                number = 0;
                handler.removeCallbacks(ChangeBackgroundRunnable);
                handler.postDelayed(ChangeBackgroundRunnable, 0);

        }
    });
```

Comment: use ValueAnimator instead

Comment: But the created program works almost perfectly, there should be a way to stop it?

Comment: Check this old stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458785/5156016).

Comment: Think about how to extend the solution proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10630973/5018798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code (again) your `removeCallbacks` method is passing in an Instance of your `Runnable` that is yet to be running.

You will need to Store the instance of the `Runnable` outside of your Click Listener. I have jsut knocked up a quick example that shows my thinking:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Button startBtn;
    int counter = 0;
    boolean running = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

        final Handler counterHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); //Just to be specific
        final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(String.format("Count is %s", counter ++));
                counterHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };


        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(running) {
                    counterHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                    running = false;
                } else {
                    counterHandler.post(myRunnable);
                    running = true;
                }


            }
        });

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.com.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvCounter"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/startBtn" android:text="Start Stop Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, your suggestion is working perfectly!