# How to stop a runnable within the runnable?

Tags: java, runnable

I'm trying to create a runnable that will test to see if you're dead (health below 1) and if you are dead, then it will stop the runnable. If you aren't it will keep going. But I can't find a way to stop the runnable. Is there any way to stop the runnable within the runnable with a script?

Note that the runnable is being run through a thread:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableName);
thread1.start();
```

Runnable Example:

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (health < 1) {
                // How do i stop the runnable?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything special, just reach the end of your `run` method and the thread will terminate.

Comment: The script that checks to see if you're dead is in a while loop.

Comment: So exit the while loop.

Comment: In that case, you can either add a volatile boolean that would break your loop, or interrupt a thread that runs your code.

Comment: make sure there is some synchronization while checking health

Comment: Why do you need a separate thread to check for deadness? Shouldn't you just check it whenever health is decreased, and if it's below 1 you set some `isDead` variable to `true`, which would affect a `while(!isDead)` loop in some relevant part of your code.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630737/how-to-stop-a-thread-created-by-implementing-runnable-interface

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava if you can i'd highly recommend moving to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the loop if health < 1:

```
if (health < 1) {
    break;
}
```

Or you can change the while condition:

```
while (health > 1) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) {
    if (health < 1) {
        // How do i stop the runnable?
        return;
    }
}
```