# How to handle third-party Java code in a Task submitted to ExecutorService in case it has an infinite loop

Tags: java, executorservice

Let's say I have a third-party Java library called in a `Task` submitted to `ExecutorService`.

I trust the third-party library to not be malicious, but there is a rare chance that there are programming errors that can cause it to get stuck in an infinite loop, and if this is the case, I cannot fix it to address those rare occasions.

What is the best way to handle this so that the application doesn't get stuck as well? Is [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) good enough to handle this situation?

There's a related issue [Stop an infinite loop in an ExecutorService task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358139/stop-an-infinite-loop-in-an-executorservice-task) but this relies on the ability of the programmer to be cooperative and detect `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to stop processing, which I can't rely on.

(In my case it's Jython code; in an early version of Jython [the interpreter apparently didn't check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`](http://git.net/ml/lang.jython.user/2002-11/msg00051.html), not sure what it does now... but my question is general for any 3rd-party Java code.)

Comment: hmmm.. may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853305/how-to-stop-long-duration-execution-task-e-g-infinite-loop-execution-inside but I'm not sure.

Comment: "put in a loop checking state while interrupting" - I can't, if such a loop exists, it is in third-party code.

Comment: @efekctive That makes little difference - if you wrap the method in a runnable: `run() { run3rdParty(); }` and the `run3rdParty` never returns, there isn't much you can do: if you insert an interruption check, it will not be executed.

Comment: Deleted my stuff because I misread the question. If you really need the 3rd party code I would spin another jvm and use ObjectStream or any other serialization logic. Then when the heartbeat stops, kill the process and restart or exit the runnable

Answer (score 1):

If the task has an infinite loop that does not check for the thread interrupted status and does not use methods that throw `InterruptedException`s, it won't be stopped by `shutdownNow()`.

Simple example that doesn't allow you program to finish:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  e.submit(() -> { while (true); });
  e.shutdownNow();
  System.out.println("Main is finished but the app keeps running");
}
```

One way would be to run the thread as a daemon:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, r -> {
      Thread t = new Thread(r);
      t.setDaemon(true);
      return t;
    });
  e.submit(() -> { while (true); });
  e.shutdownNow();
  System.out.println("Main is finished and the app can exit");
}
```

Comment: hmm, this works if the JVM's life cycle is the same as the caller's life cycle, but if it's a plugin and the JVM lasts much longer then it will be a zombie daemon thread.

Comment: @JasonS As long as your application is running, the task will keep running if you can't interrupt it.

Comment: grrrr. Surprised that it works this way in Java, given all the attention they pay to security privileges.

Comment: @JasonS Yes, interruption is a collaborative process - if the thread you try to "stop" doesn't collaborate, you are out of luck... See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902443/829571 - alternatives include running that library code in a separate process but it will probably increase the complexity of your code if you need to retrieve results etc...

Answer (score 1):

Following my correct reading of the question I put together this set of classes. Relatively simple: One Runnable that connects to a socket sending input and retrieving output from a secondary jvm that invokes the erratic library.

If after 3 tries no response has been received the secondary jvm is killed. But it could be relaunched. The secondary jvm has an exit hook to close down sockets.

```
class SafetyValve implements Runnable{
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    Socket s = null;

    AtomicBoolean flag;

    SafetyValve(AtomicBoolean b){
        flag = b;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                flag.set(false);
                out.print(0);
                out.flush();
                System.out.print(in.read());
                flag.set(true);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Main/Controller class. It uses a Thread class for control

```
public class Switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            int counter = 0;
            ProcessBuilder pb = ...
            pb.directory(,,,);
            Process p = pb.start();
            SafetyValve sv = new SafetyValve(flag);
            Thread t = new Thread(sv);
            t.start();
            while(t.getState() != Thread.State.RUNNABLE){
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            while(true){
                if (flag.get() == false){
                    if (++counter == 3){
                        while(t.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED){
                            p.destroyForcibly();
                            t.interrupt();
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    counter = 0;
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The secondary jvm has an standard server socket implementation:

```
class UnYielding{
    int i = 0;

    int returnInt(){
        i++;
        if (i > 2)
            while(true);
        return i;
    }
}

class Hook extends Thread{

    RunWild rw;

    Hook(RunWild wr){
        rw = wr;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("exit...");
            System.out.flush();
            rw.socket.close();
            rw.server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class RunWild {

    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;

    RunWild(){
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Hook(this));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        UnYielding u;
        int i;
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in;
        RunWild rw = new RunWild();

        try {
            rw.server = new ServerSocket(9000);
            rw.socket = rw.server.accept();
            out = new PrintWriter(rw.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rw.socket.getInputStream()));
            u = new UnYielding();
            while ((i = in.read()) != -1){
                out.print(u.returnInt());
                out.flush();
                Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.print("waiting...");
                System.out.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I have tested this against 1.8 on OS X it works as expected. If this unstable classes are needed this is one way of doing it