# Blackberry Thread Exception

Tags: blackberry

how to kill a thread in blackberry.
I am using below code in which i want to kill a thread when dialog popup.
On first time login failed it is working properly but on second time login failed it returns RunTimeException.

```
public void onAuthFailed(String message) {
        //this.invokeAndWait(new NotifyDialog("Please enter correct username and password"));
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Dialog.alert("Please enter correct username and password.");
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(loginscreen);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Terminating a thread in BB is no different from JavaME. So this question is a possible duplicate. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/671049/813951

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is not dedicated to kill a thread.  It will display a new screen. And I thing you are trying to display a screen object, that is already displayed. I. e `loginscreen` instance is already displayed. If `loginscreen` is not displayed, then there's confict (event lock) between new dialog box and screen to be displayed. Display dialog box and screen in different threads.

Check this tutorial: http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

I think it will help.

Comment: Hi, I know my code does not exist something to kill the code but i m not getting any method to kill the thread in blackberry.

Comment: To stop a thread declare a boolean variable, let say `stopFlag` in your thread, and check this variable in the thread `run()` method. When `stopFlag==true`, then invoke `return;` from your thread `run()` method.