# Java concurrency questions threads vs executorservice

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have been trolling the net the whole day. Without a real answer. I'm hoping that someone can give me some advice.

What I am trying to do build is an auto buyer type application that will need to to poll auctions and check if items I want to purchase become available.

So conceptually I'm thinking that I should be able to start a thread that runs all the time (until I tell it to stop)

And when it finds an item it should start another thread that either bids or buys the item.

I have the code all done that does the mechanics its just the threading I am stuck with.

The first issue is i have been able to start threads using thread /runnable and also using execution services

But in all instances I don't know how to get the thread to continue processing..... And then allow me to issue some sort of command that will stop the thread when I want to stop the program...

Some guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: a thread runs for as long as you give it something to do. if you want to do something periodically you can use a scheduled task which you cancel when finished.

Comment: Hi Peter, 

Yeh I think I get that. At present I am just putting a while (runningvar) until I kill the program. I'm hoping that I can use a variable in the runnable class and when I want to stop the running thread I just update the variable to false which will cause the thread to end. The but i dont know how to get a handle on the current running thread or how to call a method in the class that will update that variable .

Comment: Thread pools or [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) are used to process a lot of usually short tasks. Polling in a long-running loop is not a task which should be run this way. So, it depends on the design of your application: Do you have several quick tasks to execute or do you want longer running operations in loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you have next in mind:

1. Have thread which polls from time to time some service in order to find bargains
2. If found then another thread should be spawned for **this** concrete item for doing bidding, buying and pissing off other other buyers who don't have such a great tool.
3. Stopping particular thread if you don't want to buy item anymore.

All of these could be implemented by your own thread framework using JVM thread primitives(and it would be a lot of fun to do so!). However I'd recommend to use [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) for that. [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)  explains in detail how you can do that. In essence:

- Want to have some method executed periodically? Just put `@Scheduled` on it! (Addresses #1)
- Want to have some method executed in asynchronous manner? Put @Async!(Addresses #1)
- Regarding #3 - cancelling/stopping threads is problem by its own. Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java) question/answer. The best(and recommended) way I found so far is to use a shared variable in memory or some value in database (if application runs in distributed environment) as a flag which asks the background thread to stop.

As simple as it sounds you still need to understand what's going on under-hood and learn a bit about spring. Also `@Sheculed`/`@Async` tasks are executed in two different thread pools and you might want to update default size values for them - lesson I've learned only after production deployment :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have also been considering using a database table to control if the process should run or not. Something like a log out button which sets the logged out flag and in turn stops all child processes.... Alternatively I been looking and Synchronised variables? But haven't found any samples yet

Comment: Using Spring just to get some tasks running asynchronously may be a bit over the top. Java provides the [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which is quite simple to use.