# Cleaning up threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Java method that performs two computations over an input set: an estimated and an accurate answer. The estimate can always be computed cheaply and in reliable time. The accurate answer can sometimes be computed in acceptable time and sometimes not (not known a priori ... have to try and see).

What I want to set up is some framework where if the accurate answer takes too long (a fixed timeout), the pre-computed estimate is used instead. I figured I'd use a thread for this. The main complication is that the code for computing the accurate answer relies on an external library, and hence I cannot "inject" Interrupt support.

A standalone test-case for this problem is here, demonstrating my problem:

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;

public class InterruptableProcess {
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            getAnswer();
        }
    }

    public static double getAnswer(){
        long b4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // have an estimate pre-computed
        double estimate = Math.random();

        //try to get accurate answer
        //can take a long time
        //if longer than TIMEOUT, use estimate instead
        AccurateAnswerThread t = new AccurateAnswerThread();
        t.start();

        try{
            t.join(TIMEOUT);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ;
        }

        if(!t.isFinished()){
            System.err.println("Returning estimate: "+estimate+" in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-b4)+" ms");
            return estimate;
        } else{
            System.err.println("Returning accurate answer: "+t.getAccurateAnswer()+" in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-b4)+" ms");
            return t.getAccurateAnswer();
        }

    }

    public static class AccurateAnswerThread extends Thread{
        private boolean finished = false;
        private double answer = -1;

        public void run(){
            //call to external, non-modifiable code
            answer = accurateAnswer();
            finished = true;
        }

        public boolean isFinished(){
            return finished;
        }

        public double getAccurateAnswer(){
            return answer;
        }

        // not modifiable, emulate an expensive call
        // in practice, from an external library
        private double accurateAnswer(){
            Random r = new Random();
            long b4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long wait = r.nextInt(TIMEOUT*2);

            //don't want to use .wait() since
            //external code doesn't support interruption
            while(b4+wait>System.currentTimeMillis()){
                ;
            }
            return Math.random();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine outputting ...

```
Returning estimate: 0.21007465651836377 in 1002 ms
Returning estimate: 0.5303547292361411 in 1001 ms
Returning accurate answer: 0.008838428149438915 in 355 ms
Returning estimate: 0.7981717302567681 in 1001 ms
Returning estimate: 0.9207406241557682 in 1000 ms
Returning accurate answer: 0.0893839926072787 in 175 ms
Returning estimate: 0.7310211480220586 in 1000 ms
Returning accurate answer: 0.7296754467596422 in 530 ms
Returning estimate: 0.5880164300851529 in 1000 ms
Returning estimate: 0.38605296260291233 in 1000 ms
```

However, I have a very large input set (in the order of billions of items) to run my analysis over, and I'm uncertain as to how to clean up the threads that do not finish (I do not want them running in the background).

I know that various methods to destroy threads are deprecated with good reason. I also know that the typical way to stop a thread is to use interrupts. However, in this case, I don't see that I can use an interrupt since the `run()` method passes a single call to an external library.

**How can I kill/clean-up threads in this case?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java Thread.stop isn't recommended, but it sounds like oracle's solution is unusable for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering about whether it's safe to use `Thread.stop` or `Thread.destroy` in such a circumstance. Nothing is shared here so it "feels" safe to use *if there is no other solution*. But I'd like some reassurance on that point if possible. When I start this thing, it'll take a week to run through so I'm a bit ... \*ahem\* cautious.

Comment: Solutions: 1) `Thread.stop()` 2) Run every AccurateAnswerThread in a different process, incurring OS overhead and making your code *vastly* more complicated, but ensuring that they can't crash your process. 3) Decompile the external library and modify it to have a timeout.

Comment: Those were my thoughts, but was hoping for another solution, which seems less and less likely now. `Thread.stop` looks like the only reasonable option for now (unless I can get my hands on external source-code). Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I used `Thread.stop()` without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know enough about the external library, such as:

1. never acquires any locks;
2. never opens any files/network connections;
3. never involves any I/O whatsoever, not even logging;

then it **may** be safe to use `Thread#stop` on it. You could try it and do extensive stress testing. Any resource leaks should manifest themselves soon enough.

Comment: I think this may be safe in my case, and will give it a go. I'll leave the question open for a while longer, but will return to accept in a couple of days if no better options become available. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd try it to see if it will respond to an Thread.interrupt().  Reduce your data of course so it doesn't run forever, but if it responds to an interrupt() then you're home free.  If they lock anything, perform a wait(), or sleep() the code will have to handle the InterruptedException and it's possible the author did what was right.  They may swallow it and continue, but it's possible they didn't.

While technically you can call Thread.stop() you'll need to know everything about that code to know for sure if it's safe and you won't leak resources.  However, doing that research will clue you into how you could easily modify the code to look for interrupt() as well.  You'll pretty much have to have the source code to audit it to know for sure which means you could easily do the right thing and add the checks there without involving as much research to know if its safe to call Thread.stop().

The other option is to cause a RuntimeException in the thread.  Try nulling a reference it might have or closing some IO (socket, file handle, etc).  Modify the array of data it's walking over by changing the size or null out the data.  There's something you can do to cause it to throw an exception and that is not handled and it will shutdown.

Comment: I like the idea of causing a RuntimeException. Especially if it could be done in a controlled fashion, e.g. by implementing an interface defined by the third-party library.

Comment: Oh yes, fiddling with the data passed to the external library's method  until it breaks ... very creative ... has a certain MacGyver aesthetic to it. I might just try that.

Comment: Essentially this what calling Thread.interrupt() would do because it would receive a InterruptedException when it went to perform IO, lock, call Object.wait(), or call Thread.sleep().  But the 3rd party library has to honor those semantics in order to respond properly to the Thread.interrupt() call.  There wouldn't be any need to modify the 3rd party library to add a defined interface because if you could modify it you might as well just make sure it responds to Thread.interrupt() properly and not redesign the wheel.

Comment: Just bear in mind fiddling with the data is going to be very time sensitive.  Interrupting at the beginning while it's iterating over the shared data might trigger an exception, but after it stops iterating and is computing something unshared it might not respond to the fiddles.  This technique will require knowledge of what's going on inside the 3rd party code to achieve a reliable shutdown every time.  And knowing the insides to this level might be more work than just modifying the code to respond to interrupt().

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the answer by chubbsondubs, if the third-party library uses some well-defined API (such as `java.util.List` or some library-specific API) to access the input data set, you could wrap the input data set that you pass to the third-party code with a wrapper class that will throw exceptions, e.g. in the `List.get` method, after a `cancel` flag is set.

For instance, if you pass a `List` to your third-party library, then it might be possible to do something along the lines of:

```
class CancelList<T> implements List<T> {
  private final List<T> wrappedList;
  private volatile boolean canceled = false;

  public CancelList(List<T> wrapped) { this.wrappedList = wrapped; }

  public void cancel() { this.canceled = true; }

  public T get(int index) {
    if (canceled) { throw new RuntimeException("Canceled!"); }
    return wrappedList.get(index);
  }

  // Other List method implementations here...
}

public double getAnswer(List<MyType> inputList) {
  CancelList<MyType> cancelList = new CancelList<MyType>(inputList);
  AccurateAnswerThread t = new AccurateAnswerThread(cancelList);
  t.start();

  try{
    t.join(TIMEOUT);
  } catch(InterruptedException ie){
    cancelList.cancel();
  }

  // Get the result of your calculation here...
}
```

Of course, this approach depends on a few things:

1. You must know the third-party code well-enough to know what methods it calls that you can control through input parameters.
2. The third-party code would need to make frequent calls to these methods throughout the computation process (i.e. it won't work if it copies all the data at once into an internal structure and does its computation there).
3. Obviously this won't work if the library catches and handles runtime exceptions and continues processing.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea ... I looked into this. The input is an external class and I tried extending the class with `super(...)` calls and then checking if cancelled. Unfortunately it didn't work. One of the methods is a `copy` method that I figure the external method uses immediately upon invocation. I can override that too to create copies of the wrapper class passing the cancel signal, but that's non-trivial with the information I have available. I've sent some emails looking for source, but for the moment I'm gonna try `Thread.stop`.