# How to stop blinking of LED in Android?

Tags: android, led, blink

I am trying to make an Android app that blinks the camera LED when the user presses the blink button. I'm able to blink the LED. I have added another button to stop the blinking of the LED when the user wants, but I am not able to stop the blinking.

What should I add to stop the blinking of the LED?

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button blinkled,stop;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;

    String myString;
    long blinkDelay =200;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().hide();


        blinkled= (Button) findViewById(R.id.blink);
        stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        // get the camera
        getCamera();

        blinkled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long end = start + 5 * 1000;
                        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {


                            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                                    turnOnFlash1();
                                } else if (i % 2 == 1) {
                                    turnOffFlash1();
                                }


                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                Thread th = new Thread(r);
                th.start();
            }
        });


    }

    /*
     * Get the camera
     */
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void turnOnFlash1() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }


            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;


        }

    }

    private void turnOffFlash1() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }


            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;


        }
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the blinking, you need to stop the runnable on which you started the blinking. This is how you can stop the runnable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19894653/1239966

Comment: I'm not sure that is his issue because the last condition that will be met is `1%2==1` which will call the turn off function so even if the runnable keeps going after the second iteration the torch should already be turned off.

Comment: But then it'll go back to the while loop and execute again ?

Comment: I don't think so because each runnable has 2 conditions in which it will call the on/off methods the first is a time constraint and the second is the condition `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)` so each runnable will only call the on/off functions  `i<2` times.  Even if the runnable still runs the condition i<2 will still be honored because `i` will continue to increase and will no longer be <2.

Comment: What about this loop : `while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {..}` This'll run again and i goes back to 0.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Yes, you are correct it will continue execution and `i` is reset to `0`.  But I don't think that the runnable is the issue because inside the runnable the code to turn off the torch is called but the torch never turns off if I understand correctly.

Comment: He still needs to cancel the runnable otherwise the led will be turned on again by the runnable.

Comment: The runnable will stop itself when `while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)`  evaluates to `false`. There is no need to terminate it before that condition is met because there is a reason to let the runnable run for 5 seconds. But the real issue is why the torch is not blinking/turning off during those 5 seconds. Forcing the thread to close before the 5 seconds is up doesn't address the issue of why the turnOff function is not executing as expected.

Comment: Ah! Alright :) I am not even sure if OP still needs the answer xD

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are referring to but your stop button `stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);` is not hooked up to any `OnClickListener` so if you are trying to stop the blinking by hitting the stop button your code doesn't know how to react yet until you assign a listener (just like you did with the `blinkled` button.

On another note the following code seems to be misplaced:

```
if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
```

It's not enclosed in any of the functions so most likely it's not being run when you expect it to.