# Cancel MySQL Query Execution from Another Thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, kill

I have two threads. One is extracting data from database and another is displaying progressbar with abort button. If I press abort button, the query getting executed by another thread should get cancelled.

I know how to kill it from command prompt; but, if anyone of you is knowing about cancelling query from java, that will be help for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: @Frederic.. This will just stop the thread which was created by me. It wont stop mysql command running on mysql server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some pointers, that could help:

You can call `Statement.cancel` from another Thread to stop that statement

From the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()

> Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support
>   aborting an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to
>   cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.

Statement.cancel is supported by mysql driver since version 5.0

**EDIT**

You can also specify the maximum time a query can take by using `Statement.setQueryTimeout(int seconds)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)

Comment: is there an easy way to cancel request like this if they take too long to execute?