# Java thread dump: java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)

Tags: java, multithreading

There are a large number of threads from our thread pool waiting for a connection indefinitely because our httpclient doesn't have any timeout.

Thread dump:

```
"pool-18-thread-400" #471 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fdf37a61000 nid=0x6ed7 in Object.wait() [0x00007fde8df9e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007263acb18> (a org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.doGetConnection(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000007263acb18> (a org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.getConnectionWithTimeout(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
```

But we are calling **future.cancel(true)** with **mayInterruptIfRunning flag** set to true to kill such long-running threads after some time. These threads are still waiting for connections and are not getting freed up.

**Question:** 
 Why are these threads not cleaned up by *future.cancel*? If future.cancel would not free up these threads, What are the alternative steps to kill such kinds of threads waiting for futile?

**Adding more information about implementations**

I can't share the exact code but providing some mock example

Our ThreadPoolexecutor is having Unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue and our future tasks are all callables and we are using `executor.submit(callable)` to execute our tasks.

```
public class MockThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public MockThreadPoolExecutor(int numThread) {
        super(numThread,numThread, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        prestartAllCoreThreads();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the code leading into this? Can you post it so we have a better idea of this, and where future.cancel is implemented for you.

Comment: Why don't you set timeout for your httpclient instead of killing mannualy ? One thread same topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445224/what-does-future-cancel-do-if-not-interrupting

Answer (score 1):

Your threads are waiting on `synchronized (connectionPool)` monitor in `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.doGetConnection` which isn't responsible for interruption. According to the documentation of `getConnectionWithTimeout` increasing number of `maxHostConnections` and `maxTotalConnections` can help. It's also possible to specify timeout value in `http.connection-manager.timeout` which is 0 by default so threads are waiting for connection indefinitely.

```
/**
 * Gets a connection or waits if one is not available.  A connection is
 * available if one exists that is not being used or if fewer than
 * maxHostConnections have been created in the connectionPool, and fewer
 * than maxTotalConnections have been created in all connectionPools.
 *
 * @param hostConfiguration The host configuration specifying the connection
 *        details.
 * @param timeout the number of milliseconds to wait for a connection, 0 to
 * wait indefinitely
 *
 * @return HttpConnection an available connection
 *
 * @throws HttpException if a connection does not become available in
 * 'timeout' milliseconds
 * 
 * @since 3.0
 */
```

Comment: So, You are saying there is no way to kill or clean up the threads waiting for synchronized (connectionPool) if we missed setting out timeout?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Such implementation looks pretty questionable to me, probably it makes sense to try other http client library (org.apache.httpcomponents for example)