# How to terminate Thread spawned from ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, threadpool

I have the following problem:

I am running a server, which establishes a TCP connection with all the clients who connect in a separate `Thread` spawned by `ExecutorService`. I have an exit command, which should terminate the server including all the threads spawned by `ExecutorService`. In each particular `Thread` related to a client I have a `while`-loop, where I am waiting for client's input in the condition using the `InputStream` of the associated socket. I also have a global `boolean` variable, which indicates if the server is online. As soon as it turns to `false`, I break the loop and terminate the thread. It looks basically like this:

```
// userInput - String
// in - BufferedReader associated with the input stream of the client's socket
while ((userInput = in.readLine()) != null && serverIsOnline) { 
     //do some stuff
}
```

However, the problem is that `in.readLine()` is a blocking operation and therefore the whole server won't be terminated unless all the clients type in something. `ExecutorService.shutDownNow()` also would not work, as the interrupt is ineffective in this case, because the thread is blocked by another operation. I also want to avoid `System.exit()`. Any efficient solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: I *think* BufferedReader throws an IOExecption if it gets interrupted.  I'll try to experiment.

Comment: A call to System.exit *will* terminate all running threads, no questions asked. Thats the "hard" way.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to avoid the hard way, edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close all client sockets. All reading threads should throw IOException in this case.

Comment: How should I do this? I don't keep track of the sockets used. They are created within the spawned thread for the respective client, therefore I have no access to it.

Comment: Yes, you should track all sockets. You can do it by passing sockets to some shared holder object. I.e. `Socket s = ...; holder.add(s)`

Comment: I don't think this is the best workaround for this problem, but it worked, so I will accept your answer.