# How to check if a thread has finished in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

When I `spawn` a thread in Rust, I get a `JoinHandle`, which is good for... joining (a blocking operation), and not much else.  How can I check if a child thread has exited (i.e., `JoinHandle.join()` would not block) from the parent thread?  Bonus points if you know how to kill a child thread.

I imagine you could do this by creating a channel, sending something to the child, and catching errors, but that seems like needless complexity and overhead.

Answer (score 20):

As of Rust 1.7, there's no API in the standard library to check if a child thread has exited without blocking.

A portable workaround would be to use [channels](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/) to send a message from the child to the parent to signal that the child is about to exit. [`Receiver`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) has a non-blocking [`try_recv`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv) method. When `try_recv` does receive a message, you can then use `join()` on the `JoinHandle` to retrieve the thread's result.

There are also unstable platform-specific extension traits that let you obtain the raw thread handle. You'd then have to write platform-specific code to test whether the thread has exited or not.

If you think this feature should be in Rust's standard library, you can [submit an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs) (be sure to read the README first!).

> Bonus points if you know how to kill a child thread.

Threads in Rust are implemented using native OS threads. Even though the operating system might provide a way to kill a thread, **it's a bad idea** to do so, because the resources that the thread allocated will not be cleaned up until the *process* ends.

Comment: If the thread never sends a message, but `try_recv` yields [`Disconnected`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/enum.TryRecvError.html#variant.Disconnected), can we conclude that the thread has terminated anyway?

Comment: Not necessarily; a thread could drop its sender early (using `drop(sender);` or `let _ = sender;`, for example).

Comment: Very true. Now, if those are the only cases of false positive, then I guess the thread could receive `_sender` as an argument and never use it. This way, `_sender` would act as a lifeline.. unless the compiler decides to immediately deallocate it?

Comment: No, `_sender` is a valid variable name (unlike `_`), so the destructor will run when that variable goes out of scope, not earlier, unless you move out of that variable yourself. No level of optimization will change that.

Comment: Great! So I can check whether a child thread has exited without blocking and with only `std`. The trick is to `let (rx, tx) = mpsc::channel();`, move the `tx` side to the child thread and regularly check `rx.try_recv()` until it yields [`Err(Disconnected)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/enum.TryRecvError.html#variant.Disconnected). On its side, the thread needs to receive `_tx` and promise not to use it at all. The only downside I can think of is that I cannot enforce that the child thread won't drop `_tx` early if I it has been written by somebody else :\

Answer (score 15):

It's possible, friends. Use **refcounters** which Rust will drop on **end** or **panic**. 100% safe. Example:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    // Play with this flag
    let fatal_flag = true;
    let do_stop = true;

    let working = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));
    let control = Arc::downgrade(&working);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        while (*working).load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            if fatal_flag {
                panic!("Oh, my God!");
            } else {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(20));
                println!("I'm alive!");
            }
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));

    // To stop thread
    if do_stop {
        match control.upgrade() {
            Some(working) => (*working).store(false, Ordering::Relaxed),
            None => println!("Sorry, but thread died already."),
        }
    }

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));

    // To check it's alive / died
    match control.upgrade() {
        Some(_) => println!("Thread alive!"),
        None => println!("Thread ends!"),
    }
}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/DenisKolodin/edea80f2f5becb86f718c330219178e2

At playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9a0cf161ba0bbffe3824b9db4308e1fb&version=stable&backtrace=0

**UPD**: I've created `thread-control` crate which implements this approach: https://github.com/DenisKolodin/thread-control

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is not possible yet. But this is not the point that should really be addressed.

> Bonus points if you know how to kill a child thread.

**NEVER**

Even in languages that do support killing threads ([see Java here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)), it is recommended not to.

A thread's execution is generally coded with *explicit* points of interactions, and there are often *implicit assumptions* that no other interruption will occur.

The most egregious example is of course resources: the naive "kill" method would be to stop executing the thread; this would mean not releasing any resource. You may think about memory, it's the least of your worries. Imagine, instead, all the `Mutex` that are not unlocked and will create deadlocks later...

The other option would be to inject a `panic` in the thread, which would cause unwinding. However, you cannot *just* start unwinding at any point! The program would have to define *safe points* at which injecting a `panic` would be guaranteed to be safe (injecting it at any other point means potentially corrupting shared objects); how to define such safe points and inject the `panic` there is an open research problem in native languages, especially those executed on systems `W^X` (where memory pages are either Writable or Executable but never both).

In summary, there is no known way to safely (both memory-wise and functionality-wise) kill a thread.

Answer (score 5):

As of rust 1.61.0, there is an `is_finished` method.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.is_finished

Answer (score 3):

I think Arc can be used to solve this problem
If the thread exits, the reference counter is reduced by one