# How does Rust handle killing threads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

Is there a parent-child connection between threads that are spawned?
If I kill the thread from where I spawned other threads, are those going to get killed too? Is this OS specific?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How does Rust handle killing threads?

It doesn't; there is no way to kill a thread.

See also:

- [How to terminate or suspend a Rust thread from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26199926/155423)
- [How to check if a thread has finished in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35883390/155423)

> Is there a parent-child connection between threads that are spawned?

When you spawn a thread, you get a [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) that allows you to wait for the child thread to finish. The child does not know of the parent.

> [what happens to the other threads] in the context of a thread panicking and dying

The documentation for [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) covers this well:

> The join handle will implicitly *detach* the child thread upon being
>   dropped. In this case, the child thread may outlive the parent (unless
>   the parent thread is the main thread; the whole process is terminated when
>   the main thread finishes). Additionally, the join handle provides a [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join)
>   method that can be used to join the child thread. If the child thread
>   panics, [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) will return an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) containing the argument given to
>   [`panic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html).

That is, once a child thread has been started, what happens to the parent thread basically doesn't matter, unless the parent thread was the main thread, in which case the entire process is terminated.

Comment: If I kill the thread that spawns other threads, what happen to the other threads ?

Comment: @LudeeD there is to way to kill a thread in Rust, so the answer is [*mu*](http://wiki.c2.com/?MuAnswer).

Comment: Can you not "drop" it then?

Comment: The paragraph you quoted is no longer present at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html. Instead, there is a more ambiguous statement. I wonder whether that means there are actually no guarantees?

PR: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/87848

Quote:

> If the join handle is dropped, the spawned thread will implicitly be detached. In this case, the spawned thread may no longer be joined. (It is the responsibility of the program to either eventually join threads it creates or detach them; otherwise, a resource leak will result.)