# async testing in rust - how to fail a test from a side thread or by panic

Tags: rust, mocking, asynctest

My library spawns a side thread and I'm trying to write unit tests for it.
if the library/mocks panic I would like to fail the test.

I'm mocking with `mockall`

my lib code is something like:

```
    #[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
    trait T1 { fn foo(&self, val: String) }
    #[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
    trait T2 { fn bar(&self, val: String) }
    #[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
    trait T3 { fn fa(&self, val: String) }
    
    struct MyLib<A: T1 + Send + Sync, B:T2 + Send + Sync, C:T3 + Send + Sync> {f1: Arc<A>, f2: Arc<B>, f3: Arc<C>};
    
    impl My_Lib {
      fn do_something (&self) {
        let f1 = Arc::clone(&self.f1);
        let f2 = Arc::clone(&self.f2);
        let f3 = Arc::clone(&self.f3);
        thread::Builder::new().name("lib_thread".to_string()).spawn(move || {
            // does something in an infinite loop with lots of logic and calls out to the traits which I am mocking in the tests
            loop {
               // some logic
               // ....
               f1.foo("something happened here which is interesting so check in test if it occured".to_string());
               // more logic
               // ...
               f2.bar("more interesting things happened here".to_string());
               // more logic
               // ...
               f3.fa("abc".to_string());
               thread::sleep(interval)
            }
        });
      }
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn test_lib() {
       let mut t1 = Mock_T1::new();
       t1.expect_foo().return_const(()); // all sorts of mocks...
       // all sorts of fancy logic
    
       let mut c = Mock_T3::new();
       c.expect_fa().withf(|x: String| { 
    // some complex assertion here which failed and it was called on "lib_thread"
          // i.e.
          assert!(x == "some interesting value which should be here!"); 
          assert(false); // should make the test fail but instead get a panic on the thread
// thread 'lib_thread' panicked at 'MockT3::fa: No matching expectation found
          // test is still running and never completes
       }
       //block the test from exiting until I want to finish
       std::thread::park();
    }
```

Reproducible case:

```
    fn should_fail() {
        std::thread::spawn(|| {
           loop {
               assert!(false); // test should complete here
               std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
           }
        });
    }

    #[test]
    fn fail() {
        should_fail();
        std::thread::park();
    }
```

Comment: Tests should fail if they panic. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: ```
    fn should_fail() {
        std::thread::spawn(|| {
           loop {
               assert!(false);
               std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
           }
        });
    }

    #[test]
    fn fail() {
        should_fail();
        std::thread::park();
    }
```

Comment: `std::thread::park();` is what is causing the test hang, because the thread is parked. Any specific reason you wrote that?

Comment: replace with std::thread::park_timeout(Duration::from_secs(10));

Comment: would expect it to fail

Comment: i need the test thread to wait for enough time for the work to complete without it exiting

Answer (score 1):

The test harness only checks if the thread it spawned panics, you'll have to propagate the panic inside your own thread to the thread that invoked the test. To do this, you can return a `JoinHandle` to your thread, which is created by `thread::spawn`:

```rust
fn should_fail() -> std::thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        loop {
            assert!(false);
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    })
}
```

You can then call `.join()` on the handle. `JoinHandle::join()` waits for the associated thread to finish. If the child thread panics, `Err` is returned with the parameter given to `panic!`. In this way, the panic is propagated to the main thread:

```rust
#[test]
fn test() {
    let join_handle = should_fail();
    // unwrap will panic if `should_fail` panics
    join_handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

You might not want to return the `JoinHandle` for the sole purpose of testing. However `JoinHandle` is so much more than that. In fact, [there was even discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48820) about marking it `#[must_use]`! Here is an excellent post about [Joining your threads](https://matklad.github.io/2019/08/23/join-your-threads.html).

---

There are a couple other ways to wait for a thread to finish without blocking, such as using channels, or refcounters that are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883390/how-to-check-if-a-thread-has-finished-in-rust).