# SocketException: socket closed

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I am creating a Chat application with Java Sockets, and am getting the `SocketException: socket closed` when closing the server. I receive the error **even if I never attempt to connect clients**- **just stopping the server** will have this socket closed exception.

I know what the error means, I'm trying to access the socket once it has already been closed, but I can't figure out why this would happen.

```
public ServerSocket server_socket;
new ConnectionThread(server_back_end);

class ConnectionThread extends Thread implements Runnable, Serializable
{
    public ServerBackEnd server_back_end;

    public ConnectionThread(ServerBackEnd server_back_end) /*constructor*/
    {
        this.server_back_end = server_back_end;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            server_back_end.server_socket = new ServerSocket(8080);
            server_back_end.server_front_end.display("<<SERVER STARTED>>");

            while (server_back_end.running)
                add_incoming_clients();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(); //this gets thrown when I stop server
        }
    }//end run()
```

I think the problem is in the add_incoming_clients(), because when I comment out the call, it does not throw the error. Even though I am not dealing with any clients, something happens at the `accept()` method:

```
    public void add_incoming_clients() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Socket client_socket = server_back_end.server_socket.accept(); //line 172

        ClientInfo new_client = new ClientInfo(
                new ObjectOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()),
                new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()));
     //...
     //...
    }
```

Here is the code when I stop the server::

```
 public void stop()
    {
        if (running)
            try
            {
                running = false;
                server_socket.close();
                server_front_end.display("<<SERVER TERMINATED>>");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("stop server exception, is not the problem");
            }
    }//end stop()
```

Can someone explain what I must do to close it properly without an exception?
Here is the error (line 172 is the culprit it seems, but I don't understand why)

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at ConnectionThread.add_incoming_clients(ServerBackEnd.java:172)
    at ConnectionThread.run(ServerBackEnd.java:159)
```

Comment: You closed the `ServerSocket` while another thread was calling `ServerSocket.accept()`. No mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Exception is your friend. It releases the thread that's waiting on ServerSocket.accept(), and proper handling will let you clean up whatever needs to be cleaned up before you shut down completely... You need to treat it like a friend :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know! I was trying to program as correctly as possible, and thought that this exception was not a "friend". It makes sense why it would be now that you explained it. Thank you!!

Comment: @user3487243 You are welcome. BTW, you may want to change your code to catch (SocketException ex) to catch this versus other kinds of Exceptions. It also serves to "document in code" what's going on

Comment: Good catch. In terms of running the program this wouldn't make too much of a difference I presume? It's just for explicitly catching a particular exception

Comment: @user3487243 Yes. Like I said, it will make things clearer for the next person who picks up your code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the trace and at the code, Whenever you stop(), the first thing you should do is to notify the Connection Thread for it to stop its activities - and then continue with the stop method as soon as you know the connection thread is dead.

What may happens is that the stop force closes the socket while the connection thread is using it. You can see that on the trace

Comment: how would I notify the Connection Thread? I thought I can only close the socket and be on my way?

Comment: There are several mechanisms to communicate between threads. You could share a variable flag and make the thread stop if that flag becomes true or false (and edit that flag in the stop() function). That's what they suggest here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: Ah, yes. I use the boolean variable running for this. Thank you for the reminder though!

Comment: The other thread is blocked in `accept()`. Your suggestion is unimplementable.

Answer (score -2):

The error java.net.SocketException: Socket closed can occur

> if the server expects a secure connection (HTTPS) but the client is
> attempting to connect via an insecure connection (HTTP).

1. To fix this issue, you should use HTTPS instead of HTTP for your API
   requests. Update the URL in your Android app to use
   [https://******.com/api/][1] instead of `http://*****.com/api/`
2. Additionally, ensure that your server supports HTTPS and has a valid
   SSL certificate configured. Using HTTPS ensures that the data transmitted between your app and the server is encrypted, providingbetter security and preventing interception of sensitive information.

.

Comment: No, it can't occur for this reason. It occurs when *you* close your `Socket` and then continue to use it, as in the OP's question. where he closes the `ServerSocket` while another thread calls `ServerSocket.accept()`. Nothing to do with HTTP or HTTPS whatsoever, not that there is anything in the question about HTTP or HTTPS in the first place.

Comment: I was experiencing this issue especially when handling backend apis in android. during signup It was giving a random exception `socket closed` How do i solve this issue