# Multithreading Thread restart

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

i'am writing a small app to remote control a (Behringer x32) Mixing console. And i got a problem with the communication.

I'am sending data from the pc (app) to the console (port 10023 UDP Protocol), then the console answers to the port from the pc has send data, (random port).
So i have 2 Threads one for sending data, and one for listening for data from the console..... so every time i send data to the console, i need to change the listening port... so i have to kill the listening thread and start it new.

But after some time a have and the app has about x1000 threads open.

How can i restart the Thread or update the listening port without create a new thread?

here's the code for this section, the whole files are @ [gihub](https://github.com/boscho87/x32StageWork/tree/master/src/ch/itscoing/x32StageWork/app/logic/server)

the listening thread class:

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {

    private List<IReceiverListener> listeners;
    private final static int PACKETSIZE = 48;
    private int port;

    public Receiver() {
        listeners = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addReceiverListener(IReceiverListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void update(String data, String adress) {
        for (IReceiverListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.receiveConsoleData(data, adress);
            if (data.indexOf("active") > -1) {
                listener.incrementWatchDog();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Convert the argument to ensure that is it valid
            // Construct the socket
            while (true) {
                //System.out.println("Listen on Port:" + this.port);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
                // Create a packet
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE);
                // Receive a packet (blocking)
                socket.receive(packet);
                // Print the packet
                update(new String(packet.getData()), packet.getAddress().toString());
                //logger.addLogData(new String(packet.getData())+"  "+packet.getAddress().toString());
                // Return the packet to the sender
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }


    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
}
```

and here my port updateFunction

```
 @Override
public void updatePort(int port) {
    receiverThread.interrupt();
    receiverThread = null;
    receiver.setPort(port);
    receiverThread = new Thread(receiver);
    receiverThread.start();
}
```

and the sending thread does this, when it sends data:

```
 listener.updatePort(dsocket.getLocalPort());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you kill a thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: Im not shure if there is another solution then killing the thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not a threading problem. The problem is, that the receiver thread is stuck in the `receive` method, so it cannot react to the changed port. However, calling the method [`DatagramSocket#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#close--) from another thread releases the blocking receiver thread with a `SocketException`.

Thus, you can solve this by closing the currently receiving socket when the receiving port was changed. The receiving thread can now catch the `SocketException` and create a new `DatagramSocket` that listens on the new port.

There is no need to kill and recreate threads.

---

First you put the socket into a field. This allows you to access it from another thread, so you can call the `socket.close()` method. Second, you put another try-catch block into the `while(true)` loop, which only catches `SocketException`.

Something like this might work fine:

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {

    private static final int PACKETSIZE = 48;

    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<IReceiverListener> listeners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private volatile DatagramSocket socket;
    private volatile int port;

    public Receiver(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void addReceiverListener(IReceiverListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void updatePort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        DatagramSocket socket = this.socket;
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                receiveLoop(new DatagramSocket(port));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle error
        }
    }

    private void receiveLoop(DatagramSocket newSocket) throws IOException {
        try (DatagramSocket socket = newSocket) {
            this.socket = newSocket;
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE);
                socket.receive(packet);
                process(packet);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // port was changed -> return and restart with a new socket
        } finally {
            this.socket = null;
        }
    }

    private void process(DatagramPacket packet) {
        update(new String(packet.getData()), packet.getAddress().toString());
    }

    private void update(String data, String adress) {
        for (IReceiverListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.receiveConsoleData(data, adress);
            if (data.indexOf("active") > -1) {
                listener.incrementWatchDog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that this might still contains some bugs. It is only supposed to give you a rough idea of how to solve this.

Comment: thanks! ... how should i create the new socket ? in another method? for now i just do a recursive call on the run method .. but i think thats not a really good idea :/?

Comment: @SimonMüller Indeed, you should not call `run` recursively, because this will cause a `StackOverflowError` eventually. I updated my answer with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `DatagramSocket`, you can change the used port by **Binding** the socket to a new port rather than the used one:

```
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(new_port));
```

But remember that `bind()` method won't work unless the socket is already opened and a port assigned to it, so at the first time you have to create the socket regularly, then when you try to change the port, just bind it.

And the following is a complete visualization of the process:

```
public void video_udp_server(int port) throws Exception
{
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE/100];
    for(int i = 0; i < receiveData.length; i++){
        receiveData[i] = ' ';
    }

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try{
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    }
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);

    System.out.println(new String(receivePacket.getData()));

}
```

Comment: this does not work because the socket is waiting at the receive method i have to close the socket anyway ... or im wrong ?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that, you just have to set `socket.setReuseAddress(true);`, have a look at my updates in my answer to have a complete view.