# Thread time of execution in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread in java in which method is called..I am storing a map for each thread so that i can kill it.
My sample code is:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            executeMethod();

        }
    } );

    thread.start();
   thread.setName("some Name");
   //Create Map to save each method call as thread
    threadMap.put( "some Name", thread );
```

Now I want to stop the method calling by killing the Thread so i have something like :

```
public static void stop( String threadName ) {

    if ( StringUtils.isNotEmpty( threadName ) ) {
        Thread t = threadMap.get( threadName );

        if ( t != null && t.isAlive() ) {
            System.out.println( "Going to kill the thread:" + threadName );
            t.interrupt();
            System.out.println( "killed!!" );
        } else {
            System.out.println( "THREAD is null" );
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is when i called my stop method, t.isAlive() is false. I assume that the execution time of method will be the alive time of thread..Am i Correct or i am misunderstanding it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Execution time of the method and alive time of the thread will be different. [Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/life-cycle-of-a-thread)'s what thread lifecycle says:

> The thread is in runnable state after invocation of start() method, but the thread scheduler has not selected it to be the running thread.

So, invocation of  `start()` method does not necessarily guarantee the execution of thread. It depends on how jvm and Opetating System handles threads. A thread might stay in `runnable` state for some time, before starting `executeMethod` method or it might start `executeMethod` as soon as `start()` is called, but either of these behavious is not guaranteed. This is what [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) says:

> Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority. Each thread may or may not also be marked as a daemon. When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and is a daemon thread if and only if the creating thread is a daemon.

So, you should not expect alive time of the thread to be execution time of the method.

Comment: Both citations do not document which value should be returned by isAlive() method. With such logic, it should never return true on a single core CPU system, because is we are calling the isAlive() method, our calling code is running, so the thread is not running.

Comment: I answered the following question of OP : `I assume that the execution time of method will be the alive time of thread`. Don't think the question is about which value should be returned by `isAlive()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Threads also die after they `run()` method returns. In such case the thread will not be alive. Add the `sleep` statement into `run()` method, and add print statements before and after it to be sure about the current state of the thread.

[Thread.interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) does not kill the thread, just resumes it if its paused, and in general it is not a good idea to kill threads manually. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java) for to understand why and what to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    As per Thread Class java doc
    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Thread.getState() will return you state of the thread
which you can check if thread is still running and then can kill it.

Thread.State = getState() Returns the state of this thread.

A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:
NEW
A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
RUNNABLE
A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
BLOCKED
A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
WAITING
A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
TIMED_WAITING
A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
TERMINATED
A thread that has exited is in this state.
```