# Break while loop immediately when condition is false

Tags: java, while-loop, break

Is there a possibility to break a while-loop immediately after the condition gets false?

```
while(true){
//Backgroundtask is handling appIsRunning boolean
            while (appIsRunning) {
                Roboter.movement1(); //while Roboter.movement1 is running appIsRunning changes to false

                Roboter.movement2();
            }
            while (!appIsRunning) {
            //wait for hardbutton/backgroundtask to set appIsRunning true
            }

    }
```

I don't want to wait until the first movement is done, the while should break immediatelty and closes the Roboter.class.
And I dont want to check inside the Roboter.class if appIsRunning is true...

Comment: Use `break;` where you want to exit the loop.

Comment: I cant use break inside the backgroundtask which is setting the appIsRunning boolean.

Comment: Strictly answering your question: **no**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completele stop `Roboter.movement1()` execution immideatly, you should use another thread and execute it there:

```
Thread mover = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Roboter.movement1();
        }
    }
mover.start();
```

and when you need to stop, use `mover.stop();`

**Carefull: using `stop()` may cause wrong behaviour of your program**
[How do you kill a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: @Waeuk and consider, that `Thread.start() ` method is NOT blocking, so after the thread is started main thread will continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way to do it without re-thinking your "architecture" (which I would suggest, but depends on what you're trying to achieve would be to do:

```
while(true){
    while (appIsRunning) {
        if(!Roboter.movement1()) { //Hardbutton is pressed to stop application / appIsRunning is false
            break;
        }
        Roboter.movement2();
    }
    while (!appIsRunning) {
        //wait for hardbutton/backgroundtask to set appIsRunning true
    }
}
```

And returning false from "movement1()" when you want to leave...

Answer (score -1):

type break; where the condition fails! simple!

Comment: I cant use break inside the backgroundtask which is setting the appIsRunning boolean.