# Is Thread.join() considered killing a thread? Is it ok to run another thread.start() after thread.join()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Edit: I want to make a user input stop a thread, then another user input will start the thread.

I have a noob java question, I'm new to Threads and i want to know if when i execute `Thread.currentThread().join();`, and rerun the same thread again, will it overwrite the Thread that i just joined or will it run a new thread? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: No. Not so clear at all. What do you expect when joining (=waiting the thread to die) the current thread? And how do you "rerun the same thread" again? You should probably post some code, try it out and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I just want to stop the thread manually and Thread.stop or Thread.destroy was said to be a bad idea. I want to know if Thread.join can be used as a thread stopper

Comment: have a look here on how to terminate a thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: If you want to know, if Thread.join can be used as a thread stopper, why not asking?

Comment: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) states "Waits for this thread to die." - in your case the **current** thread will wait for the **current** thread to terminate, that is, for ever - do not join with the current Thread! You can't "rerun" a thread: "It is never legal to start a thread more than once.", you must create a new one

Comment: @matt217 You should start with your requirements, not on detailed questions on not reasonable solution attempts.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Ok so my i joined the current thread and ran a new one, but i want to stop the current thread instead of having it on wait. Doing this will only create a lot of threads on hold.

Comment: @Frito I just want a user input to make a thread stop. And it was my idea to do the thread.join then run another thread again on another user input.

Comment: @matt217 That's it: googling for "java make a thread stop" shows the question just answered on stackoverflow on top.

Comment: I think you must be a bit more specific. You can't join the actual running Thread, that makes no sense: pause the actual thread until it is finished - if it is waiting it will not finish normally. You can use a flag (or `interrupt()`) to signal a running (different) Thread to stop and, to wait it stop, call **its** `join()` method.

Comment: The javadoc for `Thread.stop()` states why not use it and how to stop a thread: [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

*Waits for this thread to die. This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.*

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
t1.start();
// wait here for t1 to terminate.
t1.join();
// alternatively, you can provide a timeout in ms.
t1.join(1000);
```

The calling thread (assume it's the main thread) will wait for another thread, `t1`, to terminate.

The term *joining* might be misleading, there is no joining in that sense of two threads, also no *overriding*.

If you are trying to terminate a thread, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java) (in a nutshell, don't try to kill a thread but make it finish it's job, it will terminate naturally after that)

Comment: Thanks for the code, what if i after t1.join(); another execution of t1.start() will be executed? Im not sure if starting that thread again will add new threads

Comment: Create another thread using the same runnable if you want to execute the code again.

Comment: @matt217 you may never start a thread twice. The JavaDoc for Thread.start (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) explicitly states: "It is never legal to start a thread more than once"

Comment: Is there a way to make a thread stop manually? Not making it wait but to literally destroy it? I want to stop that thread on user input

Answer (score 0):

Just to be really clear:  `t.join()` does not do anything to thread `t`.

The only thing it does is *wait* for thread `t` to terminate.

---

> when i execute Thread.currentThread().join();, and rerun the same thread again, will it overwrite the Thread that i just joined or will it run a new thread?

A `Thread` instance may only be `start()`ed one time. You must create a new `Thread` *instance* each time you want to start a new thread...

---

...But if you think you want your program to continually create new threads, then you probably should read about *[thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)*.