# Can we stop backend thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

In my spring boot project , i have below GET web service

```
@GetMapping("/testThread")
@Transactional
public Map<String, Object> testThread(HttpServletRequest request) throws InterruptedException {

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(i);
}
    return null;
}
```

This web service i am calling from postman and inside the web service thread is starting , thread is running 10 times .

My requirement is after calling web service from postman after 10 seconds i am able to cancel that request by "Cancel Request" button, then backend thread also should be stop.

As of now its running 10 times .

Do we have any option to stop the execution of this loop in between ?

Comment: Actually i am not talking about the thread we can say its background process , if i hit rest service from postman then this loop will start and after 5 -10 seconds i cancel the request .  
Then do we have any option to stop the execution of this loop ?

Comment: Use ExecutorService and submit your job to id, generate ID and associate it with Future returned by ExecutorService. Use another REST call to request cancellation based on generated ID.

Comment: @rkosegi  Could you please brief little bit more , how can i generate id and how can i associate with executor service and how can i cancel it by using another rest ?

It would be good if you can provide some code sample for this .

Answer (score -1):

A trivial solution would be to get from testThread method the of id of the thread, maybe with method:

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

After this you can create another Rest Controller that accepts an id thread in input and kill it.
But it is not a safe solution

Comment: Kill thread is wrong pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: @Parad   ok.. so should i use stop method to kill the thread ?

Comment: @harish-bagora it could be a solution, but not a good solution. Here you con find a great example:
[link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop)