# Spring neo4j best place to start/stop a long running process [Java]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Neo4J server

I want to have an endpoint in this server that starts a thread to save tweets of a twitterstream to the neo4j database.

I also want to have an endpoint that stops this thread.

Is the best way to do this through the `TaskExecutor` object, or should I create a `Runnable` object and save it to the service bean, that I can interact with?

How would I do this in the context of a rest API endpoint in my Spring Data server?

Answer (score 0):

> The way they recommend is to use a shared variable as a flag which asks the background thread to stop. This variable can then be set by a different object requesting the thread terminate.

Coming from [How do you kill a Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)